# Repeat table headers in print mode

Tags: css, css-tables

Is it possible in CSS using a property inside an @page to say that table headers (`th`) should be repeated on every page if the table spreads over multiple pages?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This is what the [`THEAD`](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/thead.html) element is for.  Official docs [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD).

Comment: I have successfully used that in Firefox.

Comment: These comments are quite old. As of 3/13/13 lazy spot checking shows it works in latest IE10, and even venerable IE8...

Comment: ..but not Chrome. (see next answer) Looking at the issue tracker, it looks like there is some traction on this finally.

Comment: Chrome finally supports repeated table headers for print media. This is enabled if the th has `break-inside:avoid`, and can be disabled with `break:inside: auto`. See https://codereview.chromium.org/2021703002/#ps20001

Comment: **for more explanation and walk through**. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371081/4846859)

Comment: @tvanfosson Its working completely fine but is there any limitation of height of header for which repeating header should work? In my case, it stops working when header height is bigger.

Comment: Works like a charm for server side PDF rendering using puppeteer (which opens a headless chrome page and uses the chrome print to pdf feature).

Comment: content overlaps with repeated th

Comment: safari not support??any solution

Answer (score 86):

Some browsers repeat the `thead` element on each page, as they are supposed to. Others need some help: Add this to your CSS:

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}
```

Opera 7.5 and IE 5 won't repeat headers no matter what you try.

<sub>([source](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=PrintingTables))</sub>

Comment: Neither does Flying Saucer, which I am using to generate a PDF. I will also ask this question on the Flying Saucer mailing list to see if there is another way to do this.

Comment: mother of god, at the time this was written IE5 was still something?

Comment: I have just tried the `thead` example in my CSS (IE7 compatible) and it does repeat the headings when I do a print preview. Thank you. But, I see to get a replicated row at the top of the next page. Why?

Answer (score 51):

[Flying Saucer xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) repeats the THEAD on every page of PDF output, if you add the following to your CSS:

```
        table {
            -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        }
```

(It works at least since the R8 release.)

Answer (score 47):

**UPDATE:** It looks like this may have been fixed in 2016! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826#c45

**Original Answer (2012):**
Before you implement this solution it's important to know that Webkit currently doesn't do this.

Here is the relevant issue on the Chrome issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826

And on the Webkit issue tracker: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205

Star it on the Chrome issue tracker if you want to show that it is important to you (I did).

Answer (score 12):

Chrome and Opera browsers do not support `thead {display: table-header-group;}` but rest of others support properly..

Comment: how to achieve this in chrome?

Answer (score 8):

how do i print HTML table. Header and footer on each page

Also Work in Webkit Browsers

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintPage() {
            document.getElementById('print').style.display = 'none';
            window.resizeTo(960, 600);
            document.URL = "";
            window.location.href = "";
            window.print();
        }

    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page
        {
            size: auto; /* auto is the initial value */
            margin: 2mm 4mm 0mm 0mm; /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        }
        thead
        {
            display: table-header-group;
        }
        tfoot
        {
            display: table-footer-group;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        thead
        {
            display: block;
        }
        tfoot
        {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        header comes here for each page
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        2
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        4
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        5
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        6
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        7
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        8
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        9
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        10
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        11
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        12
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        13
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        14
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        15
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        16
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        17
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        18
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        19
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        20
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        21
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        22
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        23
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        24
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        25
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        26
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        27
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        28
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        29
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        30
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        31
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        32
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        33
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        34
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        35
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        36
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        37
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        38
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        39
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        40
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        41
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        42
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        43
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        44
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        45
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        46
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        47
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        48
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        49
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        50
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        51
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        52
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        53
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        54
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        55
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        footer comes here for each page
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br clear="all" />
    <input type="button" id="print" name="print" value="Print" onclick="javascript:PrintPage();"
        class="button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just work on desktop chrome.Chrome/Safari on iphone not work!