# Does IE print [table]header and footer properly (css settings)?

Tags: css, printing, header, cross-browser, footer

I need to prepare print css style for some page. It's possible to have footer on every printed page?

I tried the code, I've found on the web:

```
display:block;position:fixed; bottom:0px;
```

but it works only in Firefox.

I can try to fix it with table, but in Q. here: [CSS: Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/css-repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode) is info, that it doesn't work in IE5 (maybe I made some error, but it seems, that it doesn't work even in IE7).

Does anybody fixed problem with printing footer on every page in IE? *Doesn't matter if with tables or without them.*

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to print headers and footer using IE current, since Even in IE8 it is compliance to CSS 2.1. But there are other tweaks to get around the problem. Hope this URL will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433064(VS.85).aspx.

PS: The URL you referenced, on the bottom of the page specifically said works only on safari.