# CSS to PDF, using THEAD for repeating header on new page

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have CSS and HTML that I will be converting into PDF. I want to specify a header on each page that, in the PDF, will repeat on each new page.

I know that I can use THEAD to specify the header, however, is there a free html-to-pdf converter that will respect the THEAD tag?

If not, are there any alternatives?

Thanks...

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for one time only, perhaps you can simply open the page in a browser and export to PDF from the Print dialog.

This way, the browser deals with correctly displaying the THEAD elements and you get your PDF output.

Answer (score 5):

The open source [Flying Saucer xhtmlrenderer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//) html-to-pdf converter respects the THEAD tag since release R8 (April 2009).  To repeat the THEAD on every page of PDF output, add the following to your CSS:

```
        table {
            -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        }
```

Comment: when I add  the cs -fs-table-paginate: paginate;why my table css :border-collapse:collapse invalid;

Answer (score 4):

Have look at [WeasyPrint](http://weasyprint.org/), it’s open-source and converts HTML/CSS to PDF. (I’m the developer.)

WeasyPrint does repeat `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` on each page, but that’s only for tables. For proper page headers, you can use the Paged Media module of CSS3 (supported in WeasyPrint and some other print-oriented engines)

```
@page { @top-center { content: "My awesome title"; } }
```

All the details are in the [css3-page spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-page/). At some point I want to write more author-friendly documentation for it, but it’s unfortunately not there yet.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/). It respects thead placement, and supports a lot of CSS. It is free for personal use at least.

Comment: I actually looked into Prince XML a lot, and it is very nice. However, ultimately I would need to purchase a server license ($4000), which is quite a bit. I'm looking for more of an open source alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For thead to repeat on every page the possible solution is to set it's style to:

```
@media print {
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
}
```

This solves the problem in most browsers, but there is still a problem with dividing table rows on page break, they break in the middle.

Although I do not know if such style is respected in html2pdf converters, there is a possibility to report this requirement to developers of open source converters.

Comment: Does not work with flying saucer, so far

Answer (score 0):

I added to the table

```css
table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

and this solved the thead problem as well