# How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?

Tags: html, css, printing, header, footer

Is it possible to print HTML pages with custom headers and footers on each printed page?

I'd like to add the word "UNCLASSIFIED" in Red, Arial, size 16pt to the top and bottom of every *printed* page, regardless of the content.

To clarify, if the document was printed onto 5 pages, each page should have the custom header and footer.

Does anybody know if this is possible using HTML/CSS?

Comment: See [Why use XSL-FO instead of CSS2, for transform HTML into good PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948)
question and answers.

Comment: This is a question that I try to answer for a long time. Looks like the key to the problem would be css elements like page, top-center, content, position: running(..). How it could look if browsers would fully support @page: 
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/going-further-with-the-paged-media-module-and-alternatives-for-creating-paged-media/1895
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/building-books-with-css3 

Some open issues: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47277 
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15548

Comment: I have posted a Chrome-compatible solution **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646835/print-repeating-page-headers-in-chrome/25880258#25880258)** that will add a running header to documents that don't contain overly-large expanses of text. Still no solution for footers, though.

Comment: **Combinative Solution**:  both `pisition: fixed` and `thead tbody tfoot` techniques have disadvantages so you should combine them, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682653/4344976).

Comment: @MohammadMusavi is right after hours of stumbiling around i found this article (https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a) which explains it in detail and it works like a charm! Someone should consider writing an answer for it

Comment: I have query regarding the height of footer and header. can we adjust the height of these two components on printing page?

Answer (score 432):

If you take the element that you want to be the footer and set it to be position:fixed and bottom:0, when the page prints it will repeat that element at the bottom of each printed page.  The same would work for a header element, just set top:0 instead.

For example:

```
<div class="divFooter">UNCLASSIFIED</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen {
  div.divFooter {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media print {
  div.divFooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work if you have an element which spans two pages (pre in my case) - the footer will be overwritten on it.

Comment: Yes unfortunately that is true, since you are using fixed positioning on the footer element it will overlap any elements that run under it.  You may be able to do some tweaking with your margins and try to get the footer to position outside of the margin of the content area that your pre is in.

Comment: It seems like webkit browsers don't support this properly.  Correct me if I am wrong though!

Comment: This doesn't seem to repeat on every page.

Comment: @Tyson it is repeating for me in a simple test.  What is your environment?  Are you making sure to declare a doctype?

Comment: What doctype should I be declaring it as?  Something other than <!DOCTYPE html>?

Comment: That should be fine. `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` is what I have in my test page.

Comment: i did a header and it repeated. but it overlap with content due to fixed position. i can only adjust the first page content but the following still overlap.. any solution?

Comment: This did not work for me, I'm using Chrome 15.0. All it does is print the element where it would be on the screen, e.g. in the middle of the page, if that's where I scrolled to. It certainly doesn't print on every page.

Comment: It didn't work for me either. I got the same idea, but it didn't work in any browser i tried :/

Comment: I tested it on Firefox and Chrome. On Firefox this solution works, on Chrome not.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205
Ticket open since 2008... no progress.

Comment: Everyone commenting that it didn't work, how about providing a browser version or some further information about what you did?

Comment: @Skelly can you please mention the environment it doesn't work for me either I have `firefox 43.0.1` and `chrome 47`

Comment: [Repeating table headers on printed pages](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826) was fixed on Chrome on Jun 5, 2016. I have the version 51.0.2704.103 on Mac OS X and it works.

Comment: @Infotekka The page I was working on had no DOCTYPE and adding that (with "position:fixed" and "top:0") got me the desired behavior. Now I just need to figure out how to make it not overlay other items on the page.

Comment: this will not appear on every page. but just one!

Comment: Header and footer not showing on every page. I want this on every page. any solution?

Comment: Works for me on latest Chrome & Firefox, not on IE/Edge though (how surprising).

Comment: it worked for me but the problem is that if there's text behind it, it will overlay, instead of push the text down

Comment: @TysonoftheNorthwest you also need to add position: relative to the parent of the footer.

Comment: To those who complained about the footer overlaying the content: put a div around the content and add `margin-bottom` to reserve some space for the footer. (Hopefully your footer has a fixed height - if not, you're out of luck...)

Answer (score 194):

I believe the correct answer is that HTML 5 and CSS3 have no support for printing page header and footers in `print` media.

And while you might be able to simulate it with:

- tables
- fixed position blocks

they each have bugs that prevent them from being the ideal general solution.

Comment: Don't trust the other answers. They might work for special cases but will just horribly break in general. There is no reliable solution until @page margin boxes are implemented in major browsers. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28Cascading_Style_Sheets%29

Comment: Unfortunately I have to upvote this one. Even though we have year 2018 … why the hack don't they give us a `@footer` with `content:"stuff"` or alike.

Comment: There is actually a specification in the making at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) to address these scenarios.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. The problem is browser vendors. You can make good-looking PDFs outside the browser using CSS Paged Media with commercial tools like these (and there are others): Antenna House https://www.antennahouse.com/formatter/, Prince https://www.princexml.com/.

Comment: I'm making this as a comment, not an answer, so please don't hit me with "OP didn't ask...". One possibility is to use a PDF generator that allows you to set fixed headers and footers and render your view into this format when the user decides they want a real "print preview" or printed document. HTML is for screen rendering and screens don't have a concept of pages. PDF might as well stand for printed document format (I know, it doesn't) and is a modality where page headers and footers are relevant. NReco.PdfGenerator is very affordable for business purposes or free to try.

Answer (score 103):

I just spent the better half of my day coming up with a solution that actually worked for me and thought I would share what I did. The problem with the solutions above that I was having was that all of my paragraph elements would overlap with the footer I wanted at the bottom of the page. In order to get around this, I used the following CSS:

```css
footer {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
}

@media print {
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .content-block, p {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

The `page-break-inside` for `p` and `content-block` was crucial for me. Any time I have a `p` following an `h*`, I wrap them both in a `div class = "content-block">` to ensure they stay together and don't break.

I'm hoping that someone finds this useful because it took me about 3 hours to figure out (I'm also new to CSS/HTML, so there's that...)

### EDIT

Per a request in the comments, I am adding an example HTML document. You'll want to copy this into an HTML file, open it, and then choose to print the page. The print preview should show this working. It worked in Firefox and IE on my end, but Chrome made the font small enough to fit on one page, so it didn't work there.

```css
footer {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
}

@media print {
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .content-block, p {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Example Document
    </h1>
    <div>
      <p>
        This is an example document that shows how to have a footer that repeats at the bottom of every page, but also isn't covered up by paragraph text.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>
        Example Section I
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero. Vestibulum bibendum molestie dui nec tincidunt. Mauris tempus, orci ut congue vulputate, erat orci aliquam orci, sed eleifend orci dui sed tellus. Pellentesque pellentesque massa vulputate urna pretium, consectetur pulvinar orci pulvinar.
        
        Donec aliquet imperdiet ex, et tincidunt risus convallis eget. Etiam eu fermentum lectus, molestie eleifend nisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam dignissim, erat vitae congue molestie, ante urna sagittis est, et sagittis lacus risus vitae est. Sed elementum ipsum et pellentesque dignissim. Sed vehicula feugiat pretium. Donec ex lacus, dictum faucibus lectus sit amet, tempus hendrerit ante. Ut sollicitudin sodales metus, at placerat risus viverra ut.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-block">
      <h3>Example Section II</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.
      </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This is the text that goes at the bottom of every page.
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I only wish there was a sample HTML document in the answer to make it easier.

Comment: @EricKigathi Noted. I'll try my best to get around to that this weekend and edit my answer.

Comment: @EricKigathi Missed my weekend deadline, but I have added the example HTML code. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @brittenb - much appreciated, you are forgiven for missing the deadline ; )

Comment: not work for the second page for the header. still overlap

Comment: @Fei Xue - unfortunately, the solution as provided only deals with the footer, and not the header. You'd have to tweak the code a bit to get it to apply to your needs.

Comment: This approach doesn't work on Safari (11.1.1), as far as I can tell. In the PDF, the red footer text shows up only once in the middle of the second page, overwritten on top of the body text.

Comment: thank you, incredible useful for printing in Electron apps, since print to pdf functionality laks header and footer options now

Comment: Hello, I am facing issue with header. The header content is overlapping on page 2 onwards. Any suggestion please??

Comment: @Dexterslab as stated in previous comments, this code deals specifically with the footer, as can be seen by the fact that `header` is never mentioned in the CSS. You will need to modify it to handle the header.

Comment: Yes I modified it but still having issue. I was wondering if anyone can suggest a solution for header if they made it work with header please?

Comment: This solution is working in chrome, explorer, edge and firefox on my system. If it isn't working for you it's because you didn't add the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">` for where 'layout.css' is the path to your stylesheet. brittenb's html doesn't link the two.

Comment: Unfortunately, if there is a long element, the first page will be blank and the next page will have footer overlap.

Comment: This doesn't work for single line <p> elements. If your single line paragraph happens to land at the bottom of the page, it will be overwritten by the footer still. Especially bad for contracts.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT did you find any relevant solution to the problem of overlapping header on the second page, I am facing similar issue!

Comment: Not sure why this has so many upvotes. It produces incredibly ugly layouts, where the headline might be the only element on an otherwise blank page, and the text not overlapping the footer is only by chance depending on the amount of text. Putting in more text makes it overlap the footer.

Comment: How do you prevent from content being printed underneath the footer???

Answer (score 61):

The magic solution is really putting everything in a single table.

- **thead**: this is for the repeated header.
- **tfoot**: the repeated footer.
- **tbody**: the content.

and make a single tr, td and put every thing in a div

***CODE***::

```html
<table class="report-container">
   <thead class="report-header">
     <tr>
        <th class="report-header-cell">
           <div class="header-info">
            ...
           </div>
         </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class="report-footer">
      <tr>
         <td class="report-footer-cell">
           <div class="footer-info">
           ...
           </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody class="report-content">
      <tr>
         <td class="report-content-cell">
            <div class="main">
            ...
            </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

---

```css
table.report-container {
    page-break-after:always;
}
thead.report-header {
    display:table-header-group;
}
tfoot.report-footer {
    display:table-footer-group;
}
```

---

#### **extra**: to prevent overlapping with multiple pages. like:

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
    <div class="article">
        ...
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

which results in overflow that will make things overlap with the header within the page breaks..

so >> use: `page-break-inside: avoid !important;` with this class `article`.

```css
table.report-container div.article {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Best solution here. A few notes: Flexbox may cause some unexpected behavior. If you want footer on lsat page to be a the bottom you will need that solution and solution from @Infotekka combined.

Comment: Solution very interessing. I create a demo on https://jsfiddle.net/0ptw2emc/

Comment: Building designs in tables... really brings back memories... not good ones though.

Answer (score 57):

Muhammad Musavi's comment is the best answer, so here it is surfaced as an actual Answer:

`thead/tfoot` are automatically repeated on the top and bottom of each page. However, tfoot isn't sticky to the bottom of the last page.

`position: fixed` in print will repeat on each page, and the footer will stick to the bottom of all pages including the last one - but, it won't create space for its contents.

Combine them:

HTML:

```
<header>(repeated header)</header>

<table class=paging><thead><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>

(content goes here)

</td></tr></tbody><tfoot><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tfoot></table>

<footer>(repeated footer)</footer>
```

CSS:

```
@page {
    size: letter;
    margin: .5in;
}

@media print {
    table.paging thead td, table.paging tfoot td {
        height: .5in;
    }
}

header, footer {
    width: 100%; height: .5in;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

@media print {
    header, footer {
        position: fixed;
    }
    
    footer {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of niceties you can add in here, but I've intentionally slashed this to the bare minimum to get a cleanly rendering header and footer, appearing once on-screen and at the top and bottom of every printed page.

https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a

Comment: Yes! Also, great job with the article and the demo, thanks @Chris!

Comment: Wow, took a while to find this but it is gold !  I wish I had 400 more votes to add to this to bump it up to the top.  Scrolling down to this answer paid off.  Thanks 

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked just perfectly. The article and the demo attached helped a lot.

Comment: Any solution if the `thead` height is greater than 250px? The header seems to stop repeating if we cross height of 250px

Comment: This is working really, really great for me (thank you!). The only problem I'm having is the header and footer size is too small on every page but the first page, causing the content to overlap, any idea what to do there? Also, I'm interested to know why you've split the styling between multiple `@media print{}` actions?

Comment: tfoot td {  height: .5in;  } the trick worked for me, thanks @Chris for the solution

Comment: And somehow Chrome and Firefox managed to mess it up again. Chrome 92 and the example in the linked article starts with two pages with only the header and footer, but no content. In Firefox 91 on the other hand, the footer is completely missing in the print preview.

Answer (score 17):

I have been searching for years for a solution and found this post on [how to print a footer that works on multiple pages without overlapping page content.](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/247645/Print-html-table-into-A4-size)

My requirement was IE8, so far I have found that this does not work in Chrome. [**update**]As of 1 March 2018, it works in Chrome as well

This example uses tables and the tfoot element by setting the css style:

```
tfoot {display: table-footer-group;}
```

Comment: this works in all browsers and in asp (which has some crazy issue with page footers) Use this i say.

Comment: @DWolf First comment give me a huge hope. And you destroy me in one sentence just after that.

Comment: I actually have had this work in Chrome. I didn't have it work in a very old version of linux based Chromium but Chrome worked just great.

Answer (score 11):

Use [page breaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533037#setting_page_breaks_) to define the styles in CSS:

```
@media all
  {
  #page-one, .footer, .page-break { display:none; }
  }

@media print
  {
  #page-one, .footer, .page-break   
    { 
    display: block;
    color:red; 
    font-family:Arial; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    }
  .page-break
    {
    page-break-before:always;
    } 
}
```

Then add the markup in the document at the appropriate places:

```
<h2 id="page-one">unclassified</h2>
<!-- content block -->
<h2 class="footer">unclassified</h2>
<h2 class="page-break">unclassified</h2>
<!-- content block -->
<h2 class="footer">unclassified</h2>
<h2 class="page-break">unclassified</h2>
<!-- content block -->
<h2 class="footer">unclassified</h2>
<h2 class="page-break">unclassified</h2>
<!-- content block -->
<h2 class="footer">unclassified</h2>
<h2 class="page-break">unclassified</h2>
```

**References**

- [CSS Paged Media: Page Breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#page-breaks)
- [MDN: page-break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before)
- [MDN: break-before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before)
- [Multi-column Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673534)
- [XHTML Print: Second Edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-print/)
- [Webkit Bug 5097: CSS2 page-break-after does not work](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5097)
- [Print HTML FAQ: Will the program respect CSS styles such as page-break-after?](http://www.printhtml.com/faq.php#CSS)
- [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/1113772)

Comment: This does not print a header and footer on each page. It specifies many "pages" with best guess. If you don't know your document height (number of pages), it's useless.

Comment: @rainabba `if the document was printed onto 5 pages`

Comment: that was just an example. should not be used to precisely guide your ans.. workaround.

Comment: @igorsantos07 `should` does not mean `don't`. `If`(just an example) the word `if`(just an example) is used by the OP, and `if`(just an example) the OP is no longer active, is it better to provide a specific answer `if`(just an example) there are already generic answers and  `if`(just an example) the languages(HTML/CSS) and specifications in question are [designed](https://www.w3.org/People/#bbos) to [avoid indirection](https://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables) and simplify [documentation](https://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html)? `If`(just an example) so, why? Otherwise, why not?

Answer (score 10):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8356881/901048) -- add the following styles to a print-only stylesheet. This solution will work in IE and Firefox, but [not in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826) (as of version 21):

```
#header {
  display: table-header-group;
}

#main {
  display: table-row-group;
}

#footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Comment: I have found this solution only working one. Haven't tested all browsers but it works in Firefox!

Comment: __2017__ and still __doesn't work in Chrome!__ _but works in Firefox_

Comment: @MehdiDehghani: my bad.. taking off the comment

Answer (score 5):

I tried to fight this futile battle combining tfoot & css rules but it only worked on Firefox :(. When using plain css, the content flows over the footer. When using tfoot, the footer on the last page does not stay nicely on the bottom. This is because table footers are meant for tables, not physical pages. Tested on Chrome 16, Opera 11, Firefox 3 & 6 and IE6.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Header & Footer test</title>

<style>

  @media screen {
    div#footer_wrapper {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  @media print {
    tfoot { visibility: hidden; }

    div#footer_wrapper {
      margin: 0px 2px 0px 7px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }

    div#footer_content {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="footer_wrapper">
  <div id="footer_content">
    Total 4923
  </div>
</div>


<TABLE CELLPADDING=6>

<THEAD>
<TR> <TH>Weekday</TH> <TH>Date</TH> <TH>Manager</TH> <TH>Qty</TH> </TR>
</THEAD>

<TBODY>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Mon</TD> <TD>09/11</TD> <TD>Kelsey</TD>  <TD>639</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Tue</TD> <TD>09/12</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>596</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Wed</TD> <TD>09/13</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>1135</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Thu</TD> <TD>09/14</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>1002</TD> </TR>
<TR> <TD>Fri</TD> <TD>09/15</TD> <TD>Randy</TD>   <TD>908</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sat</TD> <TD>09/16</TD> <TD>Lindsey</TD> <TD>371</TD>  </TR>
<TR> <TD>Sun</TD> <TD>09/17</TD> <TD>Susan</TD>   <TD>272</TD>  </TR>
</TBODY>

<TFOOT id="table_footer">
<TR> <TH ALIGN=LEFT COLSPAN=3>Total</TH> <TH>4923</TH> </TR>
</TFOOT>

</TABLE>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach that only works for adding headers to every page is to wrap your content in a `<table>` and then put your header content in a `<thead>` tag and your content in a `<tbody>` tag, like so:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>This content appears on every page</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Put all your content here, it can span multiple pages and your header will show up at the top of each page</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

This works in Chrome, not 100% sure about other browsers.

Comment: this works as long as our thead and tfoot doesn't have many <tr>rows, looks like thead and tfoot has a max-height set , in my case I had 9 <tr> rows in thead, when I reduced it to 3 or 5 it works

Comment: That's a neat trick! Thead works like a charm, but tfoot doesn't. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Tfoot works in browsers, but doesn't in MS word. Thead works in both.

Answer (score 4):

The real trick is to use `position: fixed` for it to show on every page, and a `<tfoot>` element to avoid overlap on multiple pages. The only drawback is you need to know the footer height, but this can be dynamic if you use JS. Something like this `$('.footer').height($('.footer').children().first().height())`. A header can be added the same way using a `<thead>`.

```css
@page {
  size: 8.5in 11in;
}

.page {
  page-break-after: always;
}

.footer {
  height: 75px;
}

.footer>div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="print()">print</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="page">PAGE 1</div>
        <div class="page">
          <div>PAGE 2 OVERFLOWING</div>
          <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
            velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page">PAGE THREE</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td class="footer">
        <div>© 1999 Footer Example</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
footer {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}
header {
  font-size: 9px;
  color: #f00;
  text-align: center;
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 11mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
}

@media print {
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
   header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    overflow: avoid;
  }

  .content-block, p {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top:1em;   //match size of header
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
  }

  html, body {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }
  .hidden-print{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  <button class="hidden-print" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
  <header>unclassified<br><br></header>
    <h1>
      Example Document
    </h1>
    <div>
      <p>
        This is an example document that shows how to have a footer that repeats at the bottom of every page, but also isn't covered up by paragraph text.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h3>
        Example Section I
      </h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero. Vestibulum bibendum molestie dui nec tincidunt. Mauris tempus, orci ut congue vulputate, erat orci aliquam orci, sed eleifend orci dui sed tellus. Pellentesque pellentesque massa vulputate urna pretium, consectetur pulvinar orci pulvinar.
        
        Donec aliquet imperdiet ex, et tincidunt risus convallis eget. Etiam eu fermentum lectus, molestie eleifend nisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam dignissim, erat vitae congue molestie, ante urna sagittis est, et sagittis lacus risus vitae est. Sed elementum ipsum et pellentesque dignissim. Sed vehicula feugiat pretium. Donec ex lacus, dictum faucibus lectus sit amet, tempus hendrerit ante. Ut sollicitudin sodales metus, at placerat risus viverra ut.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content-block">
      <h3>Example Section II</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero. Vestibulum bibendum molestie dui nec tincidunt. Mauris tempus, orci ut congue vulputate, erat orci aliquam orci, sed eleifend orci dui sed tellus. Pellentesque pellentesque massa vulputate urna pretium, consectetur pulvinar orci pulvinar.
        
        Donec aliquet imperdiet ex, et tincidunt risus convallis eget. Etiam eu fermentum lectus, molestie eleifend nisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam dignissim, erat vitae congue molestie, ante urna sagittis est, et sagittis lacus risus vitae est. Sed elementum ipsum et pellentesque dignissim. Sed vehicula feugiat pretium. Donec ex lacus, dictum faucibus lectus sit amet, tempus hendrerit ante. Ut sollicitudin sodales metus, at placerat risus viverra ut.
        
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.
        
        Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.
        
        Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero.
      </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
      This is the text that goes at the bottom of every page.
    </footer>
   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's sample works just this, if i want to create dynamic out html. That's now work.

Answer (score 3):

My document has big header and footer, over 250px. The header, footer need to be sticked at the top and the end of the document. My solution is combined by both ideas from Biskrem Muhammad, Chris Moschini.

**Idea:**

- Put your header in `<thead>` like Biskrem's
- Put your footer in `<div class="footer">` like Chris's

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <table class="report-container">
        <thead class="report-header">
            <tr>
                <th class="report-header-cell">
                    <div class="header-info">
                        (your header)
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="report-content">
            <tr>
                <td class="report-content-cell">
                    <div class="main">
                        (your body)
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot class="report-footer">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="footer-space">&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div class="footer">
        (your footer)
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
  table.report-container {
    page-break-after:always;
    width: 100%;
  }

  thead.report-header {
    display:table-header-group;
  }

  tfoot.report-footer {
    display:table-footer-group;
  }

  .footer-space, .footer {
    height: 270px;// this is my footer height
  }

  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  @media print {
    tr td {
      word-wrap: break-word;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
  }
```

I use ejs to generate html for printing, so I don't need to work on the display in normal webpage.

Problem: This works in Chrome printer, but for Safari in my code, the footer is not showed, I don't know the root cause yet. Maybe it will have problem with other platforms too.

Comment: This works in Waterfox G4.1.2.1. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use javascipt, have the client handle laying out the content using javascript to place elements based on available space.

You could use the jquery columnizer plugin to dynamically lay out your content in fixed size blocks and position your headers and footers as part of the rendering routine.
http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

See example 10
http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html

The browser will still add its own headers or footers if enabled in the os. Consistent layout across platforms and browsers will likely require conditional css.

Comment: The provided demo doesn't even work (pages don't break, bleed on to each other, etc.), let alone with more universal content.

Comment: I should have clarified. The provided links are examples of a javascript library for laying out content across containers and is not setup for printing. This link was meant to be an example of using js to layout content within specified boundaries. I have used js as a rendering engine with wkhtmltopdf to create cookbooks from database content.

Comment: The question is about printing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised and unimpressed that Chrome has such terrible CSS print support.

My task required showing a slightly different footer on each page. In the simplest case, just an incrementing chapter and page number. In more complex cases, more text in the footer - for example, several footnotes - which could expand it in size, causing what is on that page's content area to be shrunk and part of it to reflow to the next page.

CSS print cannot solve this, at least not with shoddy browser support today. But stepping outside of print, CSS3 can do a lot of the heavy lifting:

https://jsfiddle.net/b9chris/moctxd2a/29/

```
<div class=page>
  <header></header>
  <div class=content>Content</div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
body {
  @media screen {
    width: 7.5in;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

div.page {
  display: flex;
  height: 10in;    
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: stretch;
}

div.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media print {
  @page {
    size: letter;  // US 8.5in x 11in
    margin: .5in;
  }

  footer {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

There's a little more code in the example, including some Cat Ipsum; but the js in use is just there to demonstrate how much the header/footer can vary without breaking pagination. The key really is to take a column-bottom-sticking trick from CSS Flexbox and then apply it to a page of a known, fixed height - in this case, an 8.5"x11" piece of US letter-sized paper, with .5" margins leaving `width: 7.5in` and `height: 10in` exactly. Once the CSS flex container is told its exact dimensions (`div.page`), it's easy to get the header and footer to expand and contract the way they do in conventional typography.

What's left is flowing the content of the page when the footer, for example, grows to 8 footnotes not 3. In my case the content is fixed enough that I don't need to worry about it, but I'm sure there's a way to do it. One approach that leaps to mind, is to turn the header and footer into 100% width floats, then position them with Javascript. The browser will handle the interruptions to regular content flow for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

the best solution came from biskrem muhammad.

but there is a little problem with its answer. when page count bigger than 1, footer not locating to the footer of the last page.

add this little css to your element collapsed by footer-info

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, for me it's working on Chrome, Firefox and Safari. You will get header and footer fixed to each page without overlapping the page content

**CSS**

```
<style>
  @page {
    margin: 10mm;
  }

  body {
    font: 9pt sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;

    /* Avoid fixed header and footer to overlap page content */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  #header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    /* For testing */
    background: yellow; 
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  #footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 6pt;
    color: #777;
    /* For testing */
    background: red; 
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  /* Print progressive page numbers */
  .page-number:before {
    /* counter-increment: page; */
    content: "Pagina " counter(page);
  }

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <header id="header">Header</header>

  <footer id="footer">footer</footer>

  <div id="content">
    Here your long long content...
    <p style="page-break-inside: avoid;">This text will not be broken between the pages</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Will this solution work for header with height more than. 250px. Dynamic height values / auto height

Comment: @Sebastian having similar issues with the overlapping header beyond 250px height, do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @NikhilSingh No solutions.  Height limitation of 250px  is a known accepted limitation of thead

Comment: Thanks for replying @Sebastian, did you find any other way of the printing head and footer on every page? With a bit more flexibility in the context of how `<div>`'s shrink or expand with margin of the page

Comment: I ended up with a solution of repeating header and footer for all pages using CSS page-break options Also used some algorithms to decide how many items in table each page can afford

Comment: Header and footer overlaps the content of the page. It repeats on each page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a template engine like Asp.net Razor Engine or Angular, 
I think you must re-generate your page and split the page in several pages and then you can freely markup each page and put header and footer on theme.
 one example could be as bellow:

```css
@page {
  size: A4;  
   margin: .9cm;
}


@media print {

   body.print-paper-a4 {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
  }

   body {
       background: white;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }

   .print-stage,
   .no-print {
       display: none;
   }


   body.print-paper.a4 .print-paper {
      width: 210mm;
        height: 297mm;
    }

   .print-paper {
       page-break-after: always;
       margin: 0;
       padding: .8cm;
       border:none;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

}





.print-papers {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2000;
    margin: auto;

}


body.print-paper-a4 .print-paper {
    width: 21cm;
    height:27cm;
}


.print-paper {
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    padding: .8cm;
       overflow: hidden;   
}


body.print-mode .no-print-preview {
    display: none;
}

body.print-mode .print-preview {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body class="print-mode print-paper-a4">
        
        <div class="print-papers print-preview">
            <div class="print-paper">
                <div style="font-size: 5cm">
                    HELLO
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="print-paper">
              <div class="page-header">
                </div>
              
              
            </div>
            <div class="print-paper">
                
                

            </div>            
        </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution. The basic idea is to make a table and in thead section place the data of header in tr and by css force to show that tr only in print not in screen then your normal header should be force to show only in screen not in print. 100% working on many pages print. sample code is here

```
<style> 
    @media screen {
        .only_print{
            display:none;
        }
    }
    @media print {
        .no-print {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
    TABLE{border-collapse: collapse;}
    TH, TD {border:1px solid grey;}
</style>
<div class="no-print">  <!-- This is header for screen and will not be printed -->
    <div>COMPANY NAME FOR SCREEN</div>
    <div>DESCRIPTION FOR SCREEN</div>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="only_print"> <!-- This is header for print and will not be shown on screen -->
            <td colspan="100" style="border: 0px;">
                <div>COMPANY NAME FOR PRINT</div>
                <div>DESCRIPTION FOR PRINT</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- From here Actual Data of table start -->
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1-1</td>
            <td>1-2</td>
            <td>1-3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2-1</td>
            <td>2-2</td>
            <td>2-3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found a way to fix this problem:

as you have separated each page by lets say "page" className,you can give this style to the "page":

```
.page{
  height: 1150px;
  page-break-after: always;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and go through the preview of printed pages and make sure that all contents are within the page otherwise move the content so everything would look neat.

Answer (score -1):

Is this something you want to print-only? You could add it to every page on your site and use CSS to define the tag as a print-only media.

As an example, this could be an example header:

```
<span class="printspan">UNCLASSIFIED</span>
```

And in your CSS, do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    .printspan
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .printspan
    {
        display: inline;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16 pt;
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

Finally, to include the header/footer on every page you might use server-side includes or if you have any pages being generated with PHP or ASP you could simply code it in to a common file.

**Edit:**

This answer is intended to provide a way to show something on the physical printed version of a document while not showing it otherwise. However just as comments suggest, it doesn't solve the issue of having a footer on multiple printed pages when content overflows.

I'm leaving it here in case it's helpful nevertheless.

Comment: +1 for using display rather than visibility - visibility : hidden leaves reserved space, whereas display : none collapses the whitespace, saves paper and makes planet Earth survive longer.

Comment: -1: although a good example of a print style sheet, it doesn't deal with the issue of when content overflows a page.. As is, this would only show the footer on the last page.

Answer (score -3):

Based on some post, i think `position: fixed` works for me.

```css
body {
  background: #eaeaed;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

.my-footer {
  background: #2db34a;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

.my-header {
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Header & Footer</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="my-header">Fixed Header</div>
    <div class="my-footer">Fixed Footer</div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>TH 1</th>
          <th>TH 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>TD 1</td>
          <td>TD 2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Press Ctrl+P in chrome see the header & footer text on each page.
Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, the headers and footers are printed on every page but they overlap the content of the page.

Answer (score -3):

`@Daniel` made a comment on the question in 2012 about the lack of support for the CSS3 features: `top-center` & `bottom-center`.

Well, In Chrome 73+, the following snippet works, where `header` and `footer` are `<header></header>` and `<footer></footer>` elements defined within the page.

```
@page {
    @top-center { content: element(header) }
}
@page { 
    @bottom-center { content: element(footer) }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reference you are aware of that supports this statement?  I don't doubt you ... I'm just looking to find out what else in the css-page-3 standard is supported by Chrome.

Comment: @JonathanB. I do not have a resource to share for this. I just tried to find something and could not. The only reason I referenced Chrome73+ in the post is because that is the browser I tested in.....

Comment: This does not work in any browser and at least in Chrome there has been no effort or interest in supporting it, despite a bug being filed in 2012, 8 years ago. https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_page_page-margin-boxes https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85062