# Print Header and Footer with XPage or HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpages, lotus-domino

Is it possible to print HTML pages with custom headers & footers on each printed page with XPAGE?

I'd like to add the word "Business Partner" in blue, Arial, size 8pt to the bottom of every printed page, regardless of the content.

See my sample as attachment: http://i1248.photobucket.com/albums/hh490/dannysumarnach/XPage/samplepagewithfooter.jpg

Answer (score 6):

There is no special Notes/Domino/Xpages foo necessary. Just plain HTML and CSS. There is a nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722437/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-web-page-header-footer-printed-on-every-page) that involves tables. It does exactly what you want and supposedly even works in IE6.

And as Stefan is too timid ;) to modifiy my answer, please keep the following from the linked thread in mind: "*I would say to anyone trying to do HTML reports from the browser, unless they are very simple, save yourself the frustration (as others told me here) and go with PDFs or something similar.*"

Comment: From the link: "I would say to anyone trying to do HTML reports from the browser, unless they are very simple, save yourself the frustration (as others told me here) and go with PDFs or something similar."