# Chrome print preview: any text on the bottom of every page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I'm designing a report pages and I've lost with this issue.
Does anyone know how to put any text on the footer of **every** page being printed?

I've managed how to do it on the last one or on the first one. But not **every**.

[This is code I have](http://jsbin.com/kanibezisu/1/edit?html,css,js).

[Full-page preview](http://output.jsbin.com/kanibezisu/1) (Press Ctrl+P or Command+P).

Thank you for your all advices!

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the HTML youre working with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a web page header/footer printed on every page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722437/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-web-page-header-footer-printed-on-every-page)

Comment: What excactly are you trying to do? Kepp one specific footer at the bottom of the page? Please add an example (html+css) where it is working and one where it isn't working

Comment: @MathiasHaugsbø, sounds like it.  Sergii are you specifying the height of the report page?  Do you need to support multiple formats outside of 8.5x11?

Comment: @cgatian Page format is static one. Correct, 8.5x11 is this I'm working with.

Comment: @PatrickEvans not exactly the same I want

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This probably wont help, but if you know the size of your reports (they dont change in height) you could try doing something like below. Use an @media query to only display the ::after content when printing.

http://jsbin.com/dabusal/1/edit?html,css,output

```css
.report-page
{
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-after:always; 
  height:880px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px dashed;
}

.report-page.report-page--last
{
  page-break-after: avoid;
}

.report-page::after
{
  content:'Footer Content ©2016';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class='report-page'>PAGE1</div>
   <div class='report-page report-page--last'>PAGE2</div>
</body>
</html>
```