# Is there a way in css to print header and footer for each A4 page, compatible with chrome, firefox and safari?

Tags: html, css, printing

I would like to print a multi-page html document, I would like to know if there is a way to repeat the header and the footer, on every printed page.

I tried "position:fixed", not working when printing on safari, also the footer is overlapping text in chrome.

I also tried table thead and tfoot, not compatible with safari and the footer on the last page is not printed at the bottom of the page on chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Printing test</title>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        width: 21.7cm;
        margin: 0;
    }

    header,
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 21.7cm;
    }

    main {
        margin-top: 4.5cm;
        margin-bottom: 2.5cm;
    }

    header {
        top: 0;
        height: 4.5cm;

    }

    footer {
        bottom: 0;
        height: 2.5cm;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="header.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </header>
    <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus doloremque sunt, dignissimos voluptatem
            veritatis, sed fuga reprehenderit nisi, in rerum ut accusamus quos iure quibusdam et? Saepe rerum sequi
            veritatis.<br><br></p>
        <p>Magni omnis numquam ipsam saepe? Id fugiat sint corrupti ab provident cum unde iusto excepturi recusandae,
            officia amet cumque eaque pariatur esse alias doloribus repellendus blanditiis! Consequatur recusandae
            blanditiis est.<br><br></p>
        <p>Illum quod accusantium, reprehenderit nam minima odio iste. In libero et, magnam placeat quasi cumque
            repellendus delectus neque ab eos inventore, odio quidem similique dolorem voluptatibus dolore consectetur
            reiciendis totam?<br><br></p>
        <p>Illo nesciunt dolorum optio quisquam facilis debitis saepe modi, officia odio itaque rem quos. Reprehenderit
            soluta aliquam quis doloribus nemo reiciendis, quam hic commodi error blanditiis assumenda sapiente, nobis
            explicabo.<br><br></p>
        <p>Magnam facilis illum, fugiat enim molestiae sit minima velit unde fugit ipsa vel autem consequuntur pariatur
            at labore architecto aliquam soluta distinctio cum! Qui enim eveniet amet optio quia voluptate.<br><br></p>
        <p>Repellendus quisquam nesciunt natus blanditiis dolorum ad voluptates fugiat vitae rerum, modi ipsa repellat
            tempore distinctio itaque velit aliquam consequuntur temporibus ut optio fugit adipisci? Quae, quod
            reiciendis. Harum, minus?<br><br></p>
        <p>Corrupti excepturi quisquam cum aperiam distinctio velit commodi aliquam reiciendis cumque neque incidunt
            consequatur, sapiente ad recusandae sequi ullam odit quasi et nostrum eos, consectetur debitis ut
            repudiandae numquam. Exercitationem.<br><br></p>
        <p>Asperiores molestiae, ea ducimus sint libero illo consequuntur reprehenderit excepturi eligendi maiores
            facere architecto ipsa voluptatem ut eius et quo sed! Est inventore ipsam dolorem unde laudantium obcaecati
            assumenda aut.<br><br></p>
        <p>Dolores iure reiciendis iusto sunt odit? Animi odit provident obcaecati corporis? Dolores itaque labore
            repellat maiores cum eos praesentium dignissimos odit alias fugit quas tenetur, ipsa vel impedit tempora
            architecto?<br><br></p>
        <p>Accusamus nam placeat, ipsam perspiciatis reprehenderit corporis exercitationem dolore quae repellendus
            laboriosam vero possimus officia quisquam! Voluptate voluptatem dolorum saepe aspernatur, error sequi
            commodi corrupti earum eaque animi voluptatibus sed!<br><br></p>
        <p>Laboriosam deserunt dolore possimus placeat ratione quaerat, adipisci, facere odio asperiores, odit impedit
            architecto optio molestias fuga nostrum? Illo optio provident quam? Voluptatum placeat dignissimos harum
            ratione impedit rerum labore?<br><br></p>
        <p>Quisquam a, ab cumque dolores sapiente, modi atque magni eos, deleniti at voluptas fuga non incidunt
            perspiciatis rerum tempore beatae! Expedita consequuntur ratione, nihil quaerat blanditiis ad harum ducimus
            nisi.<br><br></p>
        <p>Culpa cum possimus odit fuga dicta animi, incidunt harum beatae aperiam! Aut, nisi totam deserunt quia a
            doloribus, exercitationem modi repudiandae officiis impedit repellat, eveniet iusto dolore sit! Amet,
            enim.<br><br></p>
        <p>Dignissimos odit modi, eligendi hic, obcaecati recusandae quidem cupiditate nemo quibusdam eaque sint dolore
            nisi commodi quia blanditiis nostrum vitae repellendus aliquam? Culpa in, consequatur soluta laboriosam
            labore ea saepe.<br><br></p>
        <p>Facere, odio vel. Aspernatur, fuga quia inventore quisquam, alias accusantium quidem illum ad, voluptatum
            dicta cupiditate esse ipsam eveniet harum ex unde. Aliquam distinctio officia nesciunt maiores excepturi
            debitis assumenda.<br><br></p>
        <p>Autem reiciendis incidunt quos eos sed necessitatibus vel, fugit aut quibusdam quisquam, sapiente corrupti
            aliquid. Adipisci nobis repellat ut animi nostrum aperiam. Voluptas aliquam recusandae, debitis dolorem non
            quibusdam praesentium?<br><br></p>
        <p>Labore ex amet eveniet perspiciatis impedit. Error eum fugit minima id, esse vero ipsum. Quibusdam nobis,
            quis pariatur quasi autem sunt facere veritatis totam voluptate voluptas, eius enim. Adipisci,
            accusamus!<br><br></p>
        <p>Praesentium laudantium quae rem laborum libero quam? Voluptatum adipisci commodi dignissimos ullam vero modi
            esse atque laboriosam. Rerum aliquid possimus accusantium magni maiores vitae ad corrupti earum fuga,
            dolores ab!<br><br></p>
        <p>Nam blanditiis optio neque deserunt vel repellendus praesentium, molestias iusto pariatur aspernatur ipsam,
            itaque sunt, beatae culpa dolores? Delectus consequatur ratione sapiente at quaerat! Ut, rem veniam. Veniam,
            accusantium atque?<br><br></p>
        <p>Optio fugiat eaque dignissimos omnis voluptatem perferendis, commodi tempore beatae rerum sapiente voluptatum
            quas necessitatibus asperiores quibusdam recusandae pariatur dolor nam hic temporibus, deleniti
            exercitationem maiores et! Reprehenderit, minima temporibus.<br><br></p>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <img src="footer.png" style="width: 100%;">
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document?rq=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media print {
  header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Note: It may not work properly on some browsers.

Comment: I tried this, working is chrome but the footer is overlapping content text, not working in safari. Do you think is better to export content and include header and footer in PDF document?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "exporting" content and then "including" header/footer in pdf, but you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723078/12916568) solution and see if it works for you.