# Are there any thead limitations that make it not print on each page in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, printing

I have a table that has a `<thead>`, a `<tfoot>` and a `<tbody>`. It is supposed to print the thead and tfoot on each page in theory, but for some reason the thead does not if it contains certain elements together.

This works:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">This works</td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">column 1</th>
    <th>
        column 2
        </th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

This does not seem to work:

[edit]

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <h2>Header</h2>
                    <address>
                        <strong>address 1</strong> <br />
                        address 2 <br />
                        address 3 <br />
                    </address>
                 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Wikipedia-logo.svg/600px-Wikipedia-logo.svg.png" alt="Logo" />
                 <h2>Another header</h2>
                 <hr />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">column 1</th>
        <th>
            column 2
            </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>This is the footer</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i ++): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[/edit]

it prints:

```
[page 1]
    [header]
    [body]
    [footer]

[page 2,3,4,5]
    [body]
    [footer]
```

Is there a reason for this not to work?

Comment: Can you post and example of how it does not work? What is happening?

Comment: I'm afraid that browsers (even Firefox) do not implement correctly *all* the HTML rules regarding tables.

Comment: That does seem to be the case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your print CSS add this:

```
thead{
  display:table-header-group;/*repeat table headers on each page*/
}
tbody{
  display:table-row-group;
}
tfoot{
  display:table-footer-group;/*repeat table footers on each page*/
}
```

Adjust to suit your needs

**Update**

After taking your latest HTML and playing with it, I've discovered that there is a height limit to the content that repeats on each page.

I changed the THEAD to contain:

```
<tr><td><div style="min-height:251px;">Hello World</div></td></tr>
```

If I repeat the THEAD (as changed) and the TFOOT (as is)... I can use a height up to **251px** only.  Attempting to go to any greater height causes the THEAD section to not repeat.

I'll save the "debate" about whether this is a feature or a bug... but I think that if you have a repeating header taller than 250px, it would likely benefit from some shrinking anyway. ;-)

Comment: I have the styles for thead and tfoot, and they work fine in IE 7, but Firefox is still having problems.

Comment: did you define your HTML correctly? e.g. [Table][THead/][TFoot/][Tbody/][/Table] (in that order e.g. foot before body)

Comment: [table][thead][tfoot][tbody][/table] Yep, which is why this perplexes me.

Comment: what is your full HTML markup? I just tried a quick mockup with your HTML above and it worked just fine in Firefox.  Do you have a URL or larger sample?

Comment: I have updated it with an example that appears to reproduce it on my computer. Maybe the header can only be so big in Firefox?

Comment: I realise that a 250px header is a bit much, but... stupid company logos. 251 px seems so arbitrary...

Comment: I guess in your CSS for `media="print"`, you could do: `img#logo{ width:50%;height:50%;}` (adjust to whatever px dims you want/need) to print the logo to the same proportions, just smaller. Just add `id="logo"` or some other hook for CSS styling to the image.

Comment: WebKit has an open issue for this since 2008 https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for a problem I was having in Firefox in which the `thead` would show up on each page, messing up some styles in the `tbody`. I set the `thead` to `display: table-row-group;` in the print styles, and voila! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you have solution for repeating header with header taller than 250px for now?

Comment: @scunliffe Any luck with the height issue? Anyways to resolve that?

Comment: @JibinMathew not that I've seen. Although HTML can do a lot, the correct answer when print formatting really matters is... generate a PDF... there's been a lot of great tools published in the last (gulp!) 11 years... I'd peek into that if formatting is really important.

Answer (score 1):

If the limitation on thead height is a problem, then use css coding to place every header label on top of the page.

Please refer to the following link for more information:
[How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

Comment: Hi, do you have solution for repeating header with header taller than 250px for now?

Comment: same issue @120196, its Mar 2018 still no answers

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this 250px height limit in chrome also, as a workaround I have divided my header to 2 parts in order to get away with the height limit.

sudo

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <div style="height:200px;"> header part 1</div>
 <tbody>
    <table>
      <thead>
         <div style="height:200px;"> header part 2</div>
 ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding on to @scunliffe 's answer .
I have added this to my css, so it squeezes my thead to this size whenever possible and repeats it in all pages now in IE11 and Chrome 62

```
  thead {
        display: table-header-group;
       max-height:250px;
    }
```