# Header & Footer In Print Page? Not The Web browser Header And Footer

Tags: html, css

I Have Problem with Headers And Footer on web page Which is  Going to Print. My custom  headers and footer should print on each page. Header is printing at top of page, that is fine, but footer is not printing at bottom of page if the content is less on page. footer is printing depends on content.

HERE MY CODE IS:-

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='print.css' media='print'>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th align="center" width="100%">
            <font size="5" color="black"><strong>HEADER HERE</strong></font>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td align="center" width="100%">
            <font size="4" color="black"><strong>FOOTER HERE</strong></font>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
      <tbody height="100%">
        <tr>
          <td width="100%">
            CONTENT HERE
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

MY CSS IS:-

```
.thead {
display: table-header-group;
}

.tfoot {
display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Can any one suggest me how to do it ? that would great help?

Comment: Please tell better question for this. It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: You should add your CSS to the question.

Comment: Is your footer getting pushed to a second page when there is a lot of content?

Comment: yeah, the footer is printed on next page if content is less the footer print in below the content  but my wish is the footer is not depend the content

Comment: it should be footer is print bottom of the page please give me help

Comment: What you're experiencing isn't necessarily wrong, but worse varies between browsers - header/footer printing isn't standardized yet.

Comment: Please see the answer to this very similar question:

[HTML Print Header & Footer][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a `print.css`, write (only in `print.css`):

```
thead {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

tfoot {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Depending on how much height your `thead` and `tfoot` might occupy, use an appropriate `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` on the table to avoid any overlap that might occur.

Comment: Footer only shows on first page. Question specified, "footer should print on each page"

Answer (score -1):

This is the code i use. Note I am setting both html and body height to 100% (needed for Chrome and Safari). Tested and works fine in IE9, FF, Chrome.

```
@media print {
  html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Footer only shows on first page. Question specified, "footer should print on each page"