# PHP print a4 pages

Tags: php, printing, footer, page-size

i need to print some content from Mysql Db.
The problem is that EVERY A4 pages need to have a footer ( at the bottom ) with some general infos...I really don't know how to implement this with php..Any help?? Thx

Comment: You could always serve a pdf created in HTML using tcpdf.

Comment: Export your Database into a CSV file and load it with your Spreadsheet application. Then set header and footer and just print. What's the deal? If you like it more professional, checkout http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Comment: Do you want to do that automatically on regular basis or just once?

Comment: automatically!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to take HTML/CSS to include a footer on every page printed.

- [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)
- http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Printing_Headers
- http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Print_Stylesheets

Comment: Maybe you can add a `html { margin-bottom: 5cm; } .footer { bottom: -2cm; }` or something? Or maybe on the `body` element instead of `html`? Or look on my additional links in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you depend on exact formating in general you can produce PDFs. However that is a lot more complex like the HTML/CSS solution: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php