# How to Paginate Footnotes Properly in CSS & HTML (Print Media)

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, pagination

Is there a way to get footnotes to work properly, i.e. with a dynamic footnote region size and each page having only the footnotes for that page, when using the `@media print` mode of CSS3 with (X)HTML? Or can you point me to a Javascript recipe for achieving something like this?

Comment: Work properly? What is your exact problem - what does not work? Post code.

Comment: @easwee So far, following [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664752/how-to-add-print-headers-and-footers-in-html-css-and-javascript) I have something like: `div#footnote-block { bottom:0; position:fixed; }`. Of course, this puts a footnote block on every page, and it conflicts with whatever is in the main text block.

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem by working in an entirely different direction. Thankfully, I was already producing the XHTML from XML with an XSLT transform. I wrote another transform file, that went to (believe it or not) XeLaTeX; I wrote a Python script to apply the transform, then called it from a Bash build script (which had to use tail to hack off the first line, which is an XML declaration illegal in XeLaTeX) and then does two passes of compilation to produce the final PDF document with properly paginated footnotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of JavaScript libraries that do pagination (leveraging CSS, of course):

- [Pajinate](https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate)
- [jQuery Pagination Plugin](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm)
- [jPages](https://github.com/luis-almeida/jPages)
- [jQuery Paging Plugin](https://github.com/infusion/jQuery-paging)

I have not yet had time to look into them, but they might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

> I have found a solution for this problem by working in an entirely different direction. Thankfully, I was already producing the XHTML from XML with an XSLT transform. I wrote another transform file, that went to (believe it or not) XeLaTeX; I wrote a Python script to apply the transform, then called it from a Bash build script (which had to use tail to hack off the first line, which is an XML declaration illegal in XeLaTeX) and then does two passes of compilation to produce the final PDF document with properly paginated footnotes