# How to paginate footnotes properly in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

i would like to know how to have all footnotes concerning the content of a page at the bottom of this page **when printing**, instead of having all footnotes at the end of the document, on the last page.

My question is an intended duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341583/how-to-paginate-footnotes-properly-in-css-html-print-media) because i would like a solution in pure html/css (and no javascript).

Many thanks :)

Comment: i think i've found an answer [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#footnotes), i'm going to try out and if it works post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @media css style method:

```
@media print {
/* css here move the footnotes to bottom*/
}
```

This will only apply the css styles when you print.

For example,

```
 @media print {
    #footnotes {bottom: 0px}
    }
```

But I think I misunderstood your question, and actually you want to have footnotes at the bottom of *every page* for multiple pages... sorry about that.

Comment: @media print is capable of what is asked here, however it's far from cross-browser compatible, and there's no doubt in my mind he'd need js to accomplish this.

Comment: i actually do not need cross browser compatibility, i just want to create html content and the print it.