# Print header/footer on all pages (Print Mode)

Tags: html, css, printing, fixed, repeat

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">
    content spanning several pages...
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer - Fixed at the bottom of each page</div>
```

I want to print `#header` and `#footer` on *every* page in print mode. I searched a lot but nothing seems to work, even `position:fixed` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer) one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you're willing to switch over to tables for your layout (not necessarily ideal), you can do it with the `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements.  They'll print at the top and bottom of every page:

```
<table>

  <thead>
     <!-- Will print at the top of every page -->
  </thead>

  <tbody>
     <!-- Page content -->
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
     <!-- Will print at the bottom of every page -->
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

Another option is to use display `table-header-group` and `table-footer-group` but cross-browser support isn't great:

```css
#header {
  display: table-header-group;
}

#main {
  display: table-row-group;
}

#footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Comment: The CSS approach seems to work well -- apply them to a print-only stylesheet, **BUT** also add `display: table-row-group` to the main body  -- at least in IE, it will repeat on each page.

Comment: Works in Firefox too, but (as of Sept 2012) still doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: It would seem this is the only solution, and it only works in IE/Firefox. There is no solution, to the best of my knowledge (and research), for Chrome, Safari, or Opera.

Comment: 2016 and still no luck with chrome/safari!

Comment: __2017__ and still __doesn't work in Chrome!__ _but both methods works in Firefox_

Comment: Dec-2019: This is an excellent answer, and the table-header-group hack works fine in Chrome as long as you add `page-break-before: avoid;` to the `#header` and `#footer` ... according to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826#c42

Comment: The first part, meaning using table works perfectly on Chrome.!!

Comment: what if the table continues two 2-3 pages ? will the footer still be available ?

Answer (score 4):

I think I arrived too late :), but I was looking for something like this, and I found one answer that helps me (source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDgFLysON98).
I wrote the div tag before and after the content like this

```
<div id="header">Top div content</div>

.
.
.
<div id="footer">Bottom div content</div>
```

**Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>``
<style>
body {
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin:48px 0px 0px 64px;
}
div#header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#CCC;
    background:#333;
    padding:8px;
}
div#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#CCC;
    background:#333;
    padding:8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<h1>Page Heading</h1>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<p>Content placeholder ...</p>
<div id="footer">FOOTER</div>
</body>
</html>
```

... I hope this helps.

Comment: i have tried this approach but footer hiding content inside. Do you have any idea how can we setup page so that it cant be hide any content footer , is there any where do we need to add page-breaks?

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to use the mso (microsoft office css properties) in your style:

```
<style><--
@page 
{
    size:21cm 29.7cmt;
    margin:1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm; 
    mso-title-page:yes;
    mso-page-orientation: portrait;
    mso-header: header;
    mso-footer: footer;
}
@page content {margin: 1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm;}
div.content {page: content;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nisse Engstroms answer is correct. You just need to put the thead and tfoot content inside a tr to make it work.And it also is the best method because when you use absolute positioning in a div to make header and footer it will always overlap with your main body content on the next page.

```html
    
    <table>
    
    <thead>
    <tr> !-- these are important
    <th id="header"> !--- these are important
        !--- content of header here
    </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
    !---- main body here
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th id="footer">
    
        !----- content of footer here
    </th>
    </tr>
        </tfoot>
    
        </table>
```