# "Continued on next page" at page break with xsl

Tags: html, css, xsl-fo

I have a html document that a user needs to print by using File -> Menu -> Print. When I look at the document using "Print Preview", it shows 6 pages. Now I want to display a message (i.e. "Section continued to next page") at the bottom of the page, when a page break occurs. I tried lots of option but didn't get the desired result. Does any body know the solution for this problem?

Comment: What does the question have to do with XSL-FO?

Answer (score 0):

This has little to do with XSLT, more with HTML/CSS.

If you want to have a footer on every page, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer). You can have your XSLT add a DIV with `position:fixed`.

The difficult part is to have it appear on every but the last page. A quick hack that might work (not tested) is to have another DIV with `position:absolute` and `bottom: 0` that has a higher `z-index` and hides the footer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any other solution for this. The above solution doesn't fit my criteria. Is there something to do with Marker in XSL:FO?

Comment: Browsers do not natively implement a renderer for XSL-FO, so you can't use it in this case. Perhaps someone else knows an better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use XSL-FO with the browser natively (as flyx mentioned). You could implement this server-side through a button on your page, but intervening in the browser implementation of File > Print will not be possible for security reasons.

If you do choose the server-side way, you can use XSL-FO, but I'm not familiar enough with it to help you there.