# Detect a page break in content

Tags: html, css

How do you detect a line break in a div content?

Let's say, I have couple of divs on a page like this -

```
    <div id="header" style='width:500px;'> Header content </div>

    <div id="container" style='overflow:vscroll;'> dynamic content </div>

    <div style="page-break-after:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

When I print this page, if the content inside container div is multiple pages then the header don’t appear on the second or further pages. I need the header to show up on every page.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: How is this a PHP question? If you've research HTML printing then this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Would this solution work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer  Not ideal, but mainly a limitation of HTML and printing.

Comment: @ernie thanks for the link. Going through the answers..

Comment: position: fixed; top: 0; helps but in my case, the content is variable not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of div use table with thead and tbody. Table heading will be repeated on all the pages.
[How to create a table with thead](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp)