# Insert a footer after every page-break-inside: avoid on all pages jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, printing

I have create a print css for my stock list. The stock list can be 100's of pages. I want to be able to insert a custom footer on the bottom of every page I print. I am using a page break to stop content from over lapping with the footer:

```
@media print {table.Mystock{page-break-inside: avoid}}


 div.divFooter {position: fixed; bottom: 0; left:0; text-align:left; color:black;   clear:both;
                   font-size:10px; display:block; padding-bottom:20px;}


<div class="divFooter">footer</div>
```

However when I have multiple pages the footer is only shown on the first page of the print.

How can I get it where the footer is added to the bottom of every page that is printed?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer

Comment: added the footer within @media print {} however it doesnt work on some browsers?