# how to align element to bottom of page in print preview

Tags: html, css

i am trying to align the element of my html page, using css.

I have aligned the element to bottom of page, but when i see the page in print preview. the element is not appearing at bottom

i am using this css to align element to bottom

code:

```
.bel {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 38%;
    margin-right: 38%;
    bottom:-25pc;
}
```

html code:

```
<span class="bel">Text 1</span>
```

but this is not working...How can i solve this?

Answer (score 17):

I found a useful answer in: [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4121962/456456):

```
div.divFooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

So, do not use *absolute*, as @idmean suggested, but *fixed*. As a bonus, the footer will appear on each printed page.

Comment: This will repeat the div on every page I think.

Comment: @JamshaidK., yes, I mentioned that.

Comment: how to print for last page and bottom only ??

Comment: @AbhishekSrivastava that would be another question and you could search for an answer to it. E.g. [Print table footer at the very bottom on last page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33448846/456456).

Answer (score 11):

To print an element at the bottom of the page, you should define some style rules for print.
Here is the code:

```
@media print{
 .bel{
     position:fixed;
     bottom:0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `postion` to `absolute`:

```
.bel {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 38%;
    margin-right: 38%;
    bottom:-25pc;
}
```

(And remove these margins for best results)