# Headline with page number in HTML/PDF for printing

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I try to figure out a way how to get a headline in a HTML-Print. First I thought it might be a better idea just to convert the whole page into a PDF (JS-Solutions preferred) but as most of the Open Source JS-Frameworks can't convert a page 1:1 in easy steps into a PDF now I am torn between those two ideas.

There are some solutions out there already how to get a headline in HTML ([How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer))
But as you use
    position: fixed; 
the header is just flying somewhere around and hides the text on the page, which shouldn't be of course... Also I haven't figured out yet how to get a page number...

I am pretty much open to every solution. JS/JQuery, HTML/CSS...

Thank you!