# How to create a Page Header (an Image) for print using css

Tags: html, css, header

I have an image and I would like to print it on all pages as a page header in center. I tried different methods, but the image is overlapping with the page content. Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
div.pageHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pageHeader" align="center">
  <img width="600" height="150" src="logo.jpg" alt="logo">
</div>
```

I tried finding the perfect solution to my problem and I still can't able to solve.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561776/creating-page-headeran-image-for-print

Comment: @SurjithSM I tried that too.My problem still exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Print Header & Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I myself came up with a solution.

By Using `position:fixed` the header logo will overlap with the content which is underneath it.The best way is to tweak the existing code with tables and in your css use `thead { display: table-header-group; }`

**CSS:**

```
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
    #logo
    {
      thead { display: table-header-group; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this :

```
<div id="header">
<img width="600" height="150" src="logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
</div>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
#header {
    height: ...px;
    border: solid;
    margin-left: ...px;
}
img {
    margin-left: ...px;
    z-index:...;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I will try your answer and i will get back to you in a while.

Comment: it is not working.The Image is not appearing on all printed pages.It is appearing on the first page.

Comment: to include the header/footer on every page you might use server-side includes or if you have any pages being generated with PHP or ASP you could simply code it in to a common file.

Comment: My pages are generated by using Ruby On Rails.Could you tell how to code it in to a common file?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `background-image` on div. I do it all the time.

```
<div class='header'></div>
```

css code:

```
.header{
width:600px;height:150px;
background-image:url('logo.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Now your `image` it's glued to `div`. Check if it works (:

Comment: The Image still doesn't reflect on all pages :(