# Repeat header after page break

Tags: css, printing, internet-explorer-8, page-break

I have multiple div tags and a span tag inside each div(This is Header) in HTML. What I am trying to achieve is When the div breaks while printing, I want the span tag(Header) to repeat on the next page.

```
<div class="paragraph">
      <div class="content">
           <span class="title">Employees</span><br />
           Employee1<br />
           Employee2<br />
           Employee3<br />
           Employee4<br />
           Employee5<br />
      </div>
</div>
<div class="paragraph">
      <div class="content">
           <span class="title">Departments</span><br />
           Department1<br />
           Department2<br />
           Department3<br />
           Department4<br />
           Department5<br />
      </div>
</div>
```

I understand that changing HTML to tr, th, td ll solve the problem. But, I am not allowed to change the HTML. All I can do is apply properties to paragraph, content and title css classes.

So, the final output should be like below

```
Employees:
Employee1
Employee2
Employee3

<page break>

Employees:
Employee4
Employee5
```

I am strictly allowed to manipulate css only and not any HTML. I have been banging my head to the wall for 2 days and not finding a breakthrough. and the hard part is I have to make it work in IE.

Thanks

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer

Comment: @Anon Thanks for the reply. The above link talks about repeating an element on each page. But I need to repeat that element based on a condition. Repeat the span element if div breaks. I am wondering if it is even possible with CSS.