# Aligning HTML elements during print mode

Tags: html, css, printing

I have an html `<footer>` element that I'm trying to make act like a footer in a word document. In other words, the footer needs to be positioned at the bottom of the page. Is there a way to use the CSS `@media print` to move the footer to the bottom of that particular page? Also, the space  the footer has to move can vary from page to page. Is there a way to restrict that element from moving farther than a certain distance?

**MY CODE**

```
footer p {
    color: green;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: none;
}

footer div {
    color: green;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    footer p {
        display: block !important;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    footer div {
        display: block !important;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

The `div` is not visible on any of the pages and the `p` is only visible on the first page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Print Header & Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

Comment: should you not just move the whole `footer` to the bottom rather than the `div` and `p` individually

Comment: @Pete Nothing is displayed when I try that.

Comment: @Paulie_D That solution does not seem to work with my current code.