# Invoice footer is not printing on bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying  to print a Invoice using default `window.print()`

**Problem:** Invoice is printing fine but footer is not printing on bottom of printed page as same as original invoice.

**i want:**
footer should come at the bottom in every condition on first or last page(in case of long invoice)

If invoice is lengthy then footer should come on the last page bottom.

**JS fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/bsjmq1pp/

I am using Twitter Bootstrap layout

**invoiced sample code**
https://github.com/sitepointweb/bootstrap-invoice/blob/master/sample-invoice.html
[image]

Comment: Prints for me in firefox and chrome.

Comment: You want to force the footer to print on the bottom of a printed page? Not going to happen. It will print after the end of the table.

Comment: @Christina yes same. i want to print the Footer on bottom of printed page

Comment: If you need control over the printed page layout to that extent, look into generating a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media print {
    .invoiceFooter {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

### EDIT   #

Just found this [SO Question, Print header and footer on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/html-print-header-footer)

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you.
Make footer always bottom:

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bsjmq1pp/2/

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
padding:10px;
background:#5ee;
}
#content {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:80px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:#ee5;
}
```

For old browser add this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
  #wrapper { height:100%; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```