# How to print html table with default header in each page

Tags: html, printing

I am creating a print option on a html table.
this table has hundreds of rows. Data are fetching from php and AJAX.
After getting this data i am creating a print option like below.

```
 function PrintElem(elem){
    Popup($(elem).html());
    }//
    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'width=100%');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); mywindow.focus(); //newwindow.focus();
        mywindow.print(); mywindow.close();
        return true;
    }//
<span class="trial_balance_ajax" id="print_section"> 
<!---- Ajax table data loads here----->
</span>
```

Now I am trying to print table header column in each page of printed document.
But In this case Data header only shows in first page then data overflows in others page...

> I want a Default Column header in Each page

please help

Comment: You really should not use `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What does your generated table look like? My testing indicates that if you create a table with explicit `<thead>` and `<tbody>` the header is automatically set for you:</strike>

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
            <th>Baz</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>!!!</td>
            <td>!!!</td>
            <td>!!!</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Many rows... -->
        <tr>
            <td>!!!</td>
            <td>!!!</td>
            <td>!!!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In other words, the above seems to work as requested.

Edit: The requested behaviour seems to occur automatically in Firefox, but is sadly not possible to achieve without compromises in other browsers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page) related question for suggestions.

Comment: Yes my table is as like above but default header in every page does not appear

Comment: Sorry. It seems that firefox does this automatically. I wil try and find a cross-browser solution.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you divide rows so you can create another table having header in it.

Comment: No I want  to show this report in a page then there is a print option.. so i cant do this in my view page.