# Generating PDF from CSS and HTML, more distance between @page @top-center and content

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, css-paged-media

I generate a PDF from CSS and HTML with ITextRenderer. But I dont know how to get more distance between **9. Some text** and the border-bottom of the @top-center.

This is my styling:

```
@page {
  counter-increment: page; 
  margin-top: 80px;
  @top-center { 
    font-size: 9pt;
    content: "Page Header";
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    white-space: pre; 
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

This is how it looks now:
[a http://oi58.tinypic.com/fmto5d.jpg](http://oi58.tinypic.com/fmto5d.jpg)

This is the result im looking for.

[a http://oi57.tinypic.com/sl09oi.jpg](http://oi57.tinypic.com/sl09oi.jpg)

Comment: You might be able to combine the technique here  to get the results you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the margin-top in your @page definition. The margin boxes are constrained by the amount of space given to them by the @page definition.

Edit: What happens if you set the height of the @top-center box?

According to [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/#margin-at-rules), your code should work. 
I'm using something similar in my stylesheet, and it works when I render it with Antennahouse:

```
@page portrait {
    size: Letter;
    margin-top: 28mm;
    margin-bottom: 28mm;
    margin-left: 25.4mm;
    margin-right: 25.4mm;
       @top-left {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        border-bottom: 0.5pt solid black;
        margin-bottom: 10mm;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        padding-bottom: 1mm;
        content: "Header"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: If I increase the margin-top: 80px; to for example 120px, the only thing that happens is that the border moves down. It still looks like the first picture, just further down with everything.

Comment: I got it working, but by addning a padding-top to the @page. Thanks for keeping me on right track!