# Print pages and control headers and footers with CSS

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries, document

I have created a page which replicates the layout of an A4 piece of paper. While the content may spill off the bottom of the document when I print it looks fine and splits it in the print preview (I'm using Chrome v45 but ideally this would work in all major browsers).

Now I'd like to be able to control the headers and footers for certain pages. First page only might a header but all pages might have a footer.

I have being going round in circles with this and I just want to know if this would be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page) look at the answer by Infotekka - as that might give you a good starting point.

Comment: Tried this example but the footer only appears on the first page. I think position: running(footer) is need but I'm unsure if its just the browser ignoring the rule.

Comment: Correction, Firefox is showing the footer on both pages but Chrome isn't.

Comment: Yes, seems there is issue with Chrome - my mistake as I didn't notice in your original post you specifically mentioning Chrome.  not entirely sure there is a suitable solution for you.