# Add div every time the height is greater then 11.5in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i add div every time when height of page becomes greater than 11.5in? I need to copy same div every time that happens.

```
<div class="logo-etm">
     <img src="/img/etm-logo.png" class="etm">
</div>
```

I have this code,but it wont work like i want it to:

```
$( document ).ready( function(){
    var e = $( '.logo-etm' );
    if( $("body").height() > 11.5 ){        
        e.clone().insertAfter( e ); 
    }
});
```

it puts all divs one across the other... i need them below. Can someone help?
and this is css:

```
$('.logo-etm').css('display','block').css('margin-top','-1.5in').css('width','100%');
$('.etm').css('position','fixed').css('z-index','-1').css('width','30%');
```

Comment: check your css ! or provide it

Comment: Your css is not css is JS so you have to  apply it to the new cloned node !

Answer (score 0):

Your css is not css is JS so you have to apply it to the new cloned node !
Try to apply it after node cloning !

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $('.logo-etm');
    if($("body").height() > 11.5){      
        e.clone().insertAfter(e);   
       
       }
  
  $('button').click(function(){
    // $('.logo-etm').css('display','block').css('margin-top','-1.5in').css('width','100%');
    // $('.etm').css('position','fixed').css('z-index','-1').css('width','30%');
    $('.logo-etm').css({
      'display'    :'block' ,
      'margin-top' :'1100px' ,
      'width'      :'100%'
    });
    $('.etm').css({
      'position'  :'realtive' ,
      'z-index'   :'-1' ,
      'width'     :'30%'
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo-etm">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/image/100px/svg_to_png/220732/Tribal-Kitten.png&disposition=attachment" alt="Tribal Kitten" title="Tribal Kitten by  GDJ ( https://openclipart.org/user-detail/GDJ )" class="etm"/>
</div>
<button>click to apply css</button>
```

Comment: still the same result.

Comment: your .etm seem to have a fixed position !

Comment: and how can i put clones below each other for 11.5in?

Comment: modify you css !  i ve updated my answer to hilights this ! with and without your css

Comment: @DejanJankov I have updated the css in my answer see it, and tell me if it fit your needs

Comment: I just need them to bee at distance for 11in or 1100px.

Comment: at distance each other ?

Comment: That is it... but it wont work for me... can it be its not working because i am using this in print preview?

Comment: what is "print preview" ?

Comment: printed page.... i am using print preview to print some documents, and i need that div to appear on every page of a printed document.

Comment: This is very different you have to provide `<link href="/path/to/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" />` maybe some readings for you [from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing). tell me if can help again.

Comment: yea but that is my problem.. i need it to work in Chrome. I know how can i make it work on mozilla.

Comment: it is the same for  chrome or firefox, if you do it for one you've done it for the other !

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page). Chrome has a bug for this.

Answer (score 0):

`11.5 in` is **not** a unit jQuery can work with. `$('body').height()` returns a unitless value based on **pixels**, as [is stated](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height1) in the documentation of the `height()` method. May I ask why you opted to using inches?

Would swapping the inches for its equivalent in pixels be an option? The element is properly inserted if so, see the attached example. If the `body` height is bigger than `500 px` the element will be cloned and inserted after the first element.

To make sure that the body's (viewport) height is returned properly in this case, I have given the `html` and `body` tags `height: 100%`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // What is the original logo?
  var logo = $('.logo');

  // Where should the duplicated logo go to?
  var target = $('.body');

  // What should the min-height be before inserting the duplicated logo?

  if ($("body").height() > 50) {
    logo.clone().css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'background': 'red',
      'z-index': '-1',
      'width': '75px',
      'top': '0px',
      'left': '0px',
    }).insertAfter(logo);

    logo.css({
      'margin-top': '1100px',
      'display': 'block'
    });

  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font: bold 2em sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  background: #7A59A5;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="logo">elem</div>
```

### Update

The following code will copy and insert the copied logo every amount of pixels defined in `var size`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // What is the original logo?
  var logo = $('.logo');
  
  // At what size should a new logo be inserted?
  var size = 1100; 

  if($('body').height() > size) {
    
    for(var i = (size * 2); i < ($('body').height()); i += size) {
      
      logo.clone().css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'background': 'red',
        'z-index': '-1',
        'width': '100px',
        'top': i + 'px'
      }).insertAfter(logo);
      
    }

    logo.css({
      'margin-top': '1100px',
      'display': 'block'
    });

  }

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font: bold 2em sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  height: 6000px;
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  background: #7A59A5;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="logo">logo</div>
```

Comment: can you give me example where this if is true? It wont work for me, but i want to see if this can be an option for me.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit the answer, I'll add some interactivity that'll demonstrate it better.

Comment: @DejanJankov I changed the code sample, when clicking **Run code snippet** it returns a random height for the `body` that ranges from 100-500. Clicking it a couple of times should display the behavior you're looking for I think?

Comment: Yes that is it... but it wont work in print preview if i put margin-top. the style only forks on first div.

Comment: @DejanJankov Ah, we're on the right track then. What exactly do you mean with print preview and to what element does `margin-top` need to be applied and with what value?

Comment: First div needs to be behind all elements on page and to have margin-top of 1100px appliead on top of a page. The same goes for second div, but the margine-top needs to be appliead on the first div. Hope you understand me.

Comment: @DejanJankov I have changed the code sample. Change the pixels to what suits your needs in `$("body").height() > **px**` If you want to change the CSS properties for both logo's you can now easily do so, even where you want the second logo to be inserted in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92384/discussion-between-jason-and-dejan-jankov).