# Add custom header footer in window.print which shows on every page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using window.print function to print a div content and I need to add custom header and footer which shows on every page. can some one please guide me on this ?

I able to add a header and a footer but thats only at top and bottom of the print document 
[what i can do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2PR3.png)

I want to repeat them in each page
[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWatZ.png)

Comment: Usually this is done server-side. Your question is too broad and shows no effort what you tried to achieve it.

Comment: Create a print media query in your CSS and style the elements for printing.

Comment: @A1rPun what i want to achieve is to add a custom header and footer in each page when printing. example: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BWatZ.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document

Answer (score 1):

Usualy you are not allowed to overwrite header and footer. (defaulted by browser - optional on users choice)

Did you try something like this?

```
.footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
.header { position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```html
    var pageHeight = parseInt($('body').css('height'))
 var offsetHeight=1230;
    for(var i=0;i<pageHeight;i++){
        if(i%offsetHeight==0 || i==0){
         $('body').append('<div style="position: absolute;top:'+i+';">your header</div>')
        }
    }
```

yue can play with offsetHeight

Comment: also you can just use in: <title>your header</title>