# Is there an alternative to the <footer> tag in HTML?

Tags: footer, xhtml-transitional

I see that HTML5 supports the `<footer>` tag. But I am using **XHTML 1.0** and this tag is not supported.

Is there any other way that I can implement a footer? Ideally it would only show when in print mode, and at the bottom of every page.

I have tried to find an alternative to the footer tag. But to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you use `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your html file ?

Comment: Yes I did add that to the top of the file.

Comment: Do you share with us your code so we can look at it once

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you are using XHTML 1.0? Are your documents served up with an xml MIME type?

Comment: Yes, I use XML / XSL and the content is displayed in a **CHtmlView** web browser control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use div tag with class footer and define different [css for media print and screen](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

```
@media screen {
  .footer { visibility: hidden; }
}
@media print {
  .footer { visibility: visible; }
}
```

Comment: How would you define such a footer to render at bottom of page?

Comment: Do you mean that the div element must always be glued to the bottom of the page, or that it must be the last element on the layout? If the first one, you may set the position to fixed and adjust the bottom property to 0 with css.