# How to make HTML element to be displayed only when page is printed?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, printing

I have this html element:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")" style="width:150px;height:80px;" alt="" />
```

How to make element above to be displayed only when page is printed, while in web it must be hided.

Any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: use `@media print {display: block;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Don't need to create your own CSS when Bootstrap gives you the tools...***

Following bootstrap synthax :

```
<img class="visible-print-block" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/logo.png")" style="width:150px;height:80px;" alt="" />
```

Here is some classes specific to print state :

```
.visible-print-block
.visible-print-inline
.visible-print-inline-block
```

And here is the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-print

Comment: cool,thank you! is there any way  to print img element on every printed page using bootstrap?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure... It's not its jobs I think... But check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

When in web mode - it would be hidden:

```
#printOnly {
  display : none;
 }
```

In print mode - It would be displayed:

```
 @media print {
  #printOnly {
  display : block;
 }
}
```

Place your image in `div id=printOnly`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like

```
@media screen
{
    .noPrint{}
    .noScreen{display:none;}
}

@media print
{
    .noPrint{display:none;}
    .noScreen{}
}
```