# Repeat content in every printed sheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have this structure in a web page, suppose that the table is very long.

```
<header>
   <h1><img src="//some_logo.jpg"/> 2016 Report</h1>
</header>
<section>
   <table style="width:100%">
     <tr>
       <th>Firstname</th>
       <th>Lastname</th> 
       <th>Age</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Jill</td>
       <td>Smith</td> 
       <td>50</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Eve</td>
       <td>Jackson</td> 
       <td>94</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</section>
<footer>
   <h3><img src="//some_image.jpg"/> 2016 © The report company</h3>
</footer>
```

and what I need is to print this long table but with my header and my footer repeated in every page.

Like this

[image]

I already tried with `position:fixed` for header and footer but the thing is that the content slices under the header and the footer in every page.

CSS3 rules are not effective in Chrome.

I didn't find any solution with js.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you take a look a the following question [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page) ?

Comment: Add `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` to your table.

Comment: @DavidDomain I already saw that but with no luck.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Will that help me solve my problem or is just a semantic advise?

Comment: See my answer. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example should work. See comments in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*@media print{ */
.tbl{display:table;}
.tbl > div{display:table-row;}
/* table structure is three level: table > row > cell */
.tbl > div > *{display:table-cell;}
/* special cases */
.tbl .tbl-head{display:table-header-group;}
.tbl .tbl-body{display:table-row-group;}
.tbl .tbl-foot{display:table-footer-group;}
/*} end of media print */
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="tbl">
<!-- I intentionally moved following (commented) block to the bottom
     to show that it appear at the top. For test purpose only ;) -->
<!--<div class="tbl-head">
<header>
   <h1><img src="//some_logo.jpg"/> 2016 Report</h1>
</header>
</div>-->
<div class="tbl-body">
<section>
   <!--your table here -->
</section>
</div>
<div class="tbl-head"><!--this block will go up -->
<header>
   <h1><img src="//some_logo.jpg"/> 2016 Report</h1>
</header>
</div>
<div class="tbl-foot"><!--This block go to the bottom from any valid place inside .tbl -->
<footer>
   <h3><img src="//some_image.jpg"/> 2016 © The report company</h3>
</footer>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try to print? Google Chrome print preview doesn't show header and footer on each page. FF and IE do.

Comment: I printed out from Chrome and Firefox (in case that ahve something to do with it) with no luck.

Comment: I copied HTML from your link, create a page, saved it on my dev server, open in FF 47.0.1 and print to PDF with headers and footers on each page.

Comment: Google Chrome has known bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826 which is not fixed for 8 years.

Comment:    I see...  I tried again in FF (Mac) with PDF preview and it is working. Chrome is the problem with those css rules. Maybe there is a JS solution. Thank you @Alex

Answer (score 2):

Use below CSS in your print media stylesheet. (better use class name or id selector to avoid accidently messing up with similar tags elsewhere in the page..)

```
header {
  display: table-header-group;
}

section {
  display: table-row-group;
}

footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

Comment: I guess it's not working or I'm doing something wrong http://i.imgur.com/lwDbrCO.png