# Adding Header/footer while printing html page

Tags: html, css

I've created a html page with a header,some content and a footer. I tried to get a print of the HTML page, and there was 2 pages. I got the header in first page and the footer in the last page.

What i really need is the header and footer to show in all the pages like in a word document.

Comment: you might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document-w)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your whole content inside a table, like:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>
            <!-- your header goes here -->
        </td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <!-- your content goes here -->
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>
            <!-- your footer goes here -->
        </td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

... and add the following **CSS**:

```
@media print {
    thead { display: table-header-group; }
    tfoot { display: table-footer-group; }
}
@media screen {
    thead { display: block; }
    tfoot { display: block; }
}
```

*I need to add, that this may not work in webkit-based browsers (as of now) as Safari, Chrome and Opera. Please test it on all browsers you want to support.*
*Chrome may support another option: to set header and footer to `position:fixed`, but I wasn't able to avoid overlapping with the page content (i.e. very long text over more than one page) in my quick tests.*

---

*addendum*
You may have content elements you wish to not break upon page-break - e.g. list items spanning multiple lines of text. To avoid this you can set the following **CSS**:

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
               break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
```

Answer (score -3):

There is new css trick @media print

So you just create your header and footer and hide them on the main page when is not printing. Just add to the css display:none

When its time for printing you can add media to your css and display back the hidden footers and headers with:

```
@media print {
  #id{
     display:block;
  }
}
```

also check this "[CSS page-break-after Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)"
it will give you the power to break pages

Comment: May you please add the answer on how to print header and footer on EVERY page? For example if you have a really long text which spans over more than one page. --- As I understand your answer, you would have to kind of setup your HTML to a specific print layout: elements not overlapping page borders, and the correct amount of headers/footers the print would need, wouldn't you?

Comment: you can play with css for satisfying result. .page{ height:958px } .page .content { min-height:###px; }. Adjust content min-height and var content_height according to your header/footer height.

Comment: also in addition the tables have some advantage in printing. here is some info http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/10/12/repeating-html-table-headers-on-each-printed-page/

Comment: Your last comment (with link) is exactly what I posted as answer. Your other solution would require a fixed print layout, where the user would only be able to have a good result on a single defined page layout. But you don't know how the user wants to print your website. So it's (in my opinion) bad practice to assume the user would print in a specific page layout (or even force him to do so). I'm not saying it does not work, it's just not good practice in my eyes.

Comment: `@media print` is NEW??

Comment: perhaps now its not :)