# How to make the header and footer without repeating in print for N pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, printing

I'm struggling to repeat the header and footer on each print page. No problem necessarily be a table, most like it was, someone has any idea how to do?
And i dont know how many pages it will be, can be n pages.

[image]

TRY:  [jsfiddle.net/7ZGVv/111](http://%20jsfiddle.net/7ZGVv/111)

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: I found no code to do this, the closer I saw was this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZGVv/111/   .But can not repeat the header nor footer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document with 5 pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document-w)

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith it isn`t the same.

Comment: @PedroFranco it is in fact exactly what is needed.

Comment: @PedroFranco see my answer below, please explain how this does not work?

Comment: @Danilo see the working example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since no-one seems to think it is a dup, I will post the code here to prove it. See a working example here http://a-b-smith.com/

html

```
<h1>test 1</h1>
<h1>test 2</h1>
<h1>test 3</h1>
<h1>test 4</h1>
<h1>test 5</h1>
<h1>test 6</h1>
<div class="divFooter">
<h1>Footer</h1>
</div>
<div class="divHeader">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

CSS **note I added a page break in between each of the `<h1>` to simulate multiple pages**

```
@media print {
  h1 {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
  div.divFooter {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  div.divHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  body > h1 {margin-top: 100px;}
}

@media screen {
  div.divFooter, div.divHeader {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML and CSS have no support for printing page header and footers in print.
You may  be able to simulate it with:

- tables
- fixed position blocks

This solution have each bug and caveat in different browser.

See : [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document-w)