# How to always have your header appear in the first page, but have it hidden in the following pages in your CSS printing file?

Tags: css

I have this to hide the headers in every page of my @media print:

```
.layout-topbar { 
   display:none;
}
```

However I need to show the header in only the first page of every print, haven't been able to find the way.

Comment: are your pages separated by divs or any element?

Comment: it is too small information. It would be better if you show HTML of your pages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Print, header only on first page width css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038989/css-print-header-only-on-first-page-width-css)