# HTML to PDF: Elements overlapping fixed footer

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pdf-generation, browsershot

I would like to render HTML to PDF. To get this working, I make use of Browsershot, which uses a headless Chrome to render the HTML and CSS.

This is my additional style to fit A4-format:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset(('/css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=IBM+Plex+Mono:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 11mm 17mm 6mm 17mm;
        }

        @media print {
            #footer {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }

            .unbreak-element {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: avoid;
            }

           /* html, body {
                 height: 297mm;
            }*/
        }

    </style>
</head>
```

This is my footer, which is included:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3" id="footer">
    <address class="text-muted not-italic text-xs text-gray-900 font-extralight">
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
     </address>
    <div class="text-muted not-italic text-xs text-gray-900 font-extralight">
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-muted not-italic text-xs text-gray-900 font-extralight">
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
        Text <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is: Very large elements are now overlapping the footer-section like this:

[image]

My question: How can I avoid overlapping and break the table to the next page?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1360869/2444959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682653/2444959) that answers a similar question that references [an article](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a) that might help you along.

The gist of it is that you need tables to get space reserved at to bottom for a fixed footer:

```css
.main-footer .inner {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <header>
          <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </header>
        
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <footer class="main-footer">
          <div class="inner">
            <small>© YEAR AUTHOR</small>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

This is not ideal since these are not semantic tables. I managed to get CSS tables to work in firefox like so:

```css
body {
  display: table;
}

.main-header,
.main-body {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.main-footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
</header>

<div class="main-body">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<footer class="main-footer">
  <small>© YEAR AUTHOR</small>
</footer>
```

However once I tried to fix the footer to the bottom position with

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <div class="inner">
    <!-- footer content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.main-footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}

.main-footer::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2em;
}

.main-footer .inner {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
```

...firefox the footer is painted twice (with a slight offset). I believe this is a browser bug.

All the while CSS tables won’t work in chrome at all (I also believe this is a bug).