# Body of the PDF is getting overlapped in 2& 3rd pages in VF Pages

Tags: html, css, pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUarj.png)Need to maintain same distance from logo in all the pages

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            @page {
            font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS' !important;
            }
        </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY style="margin-left:5mm; margin-right:5mm;">
```

Comment: Below is the code
<apex:page controller="RentalAgreementAsPDFController" renderAs="pdf" language="{!IF(ISNULL(language),'en_GB',language)}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="true" applyBodyTag="false" cache="false" standardStylesheets="true" >
    <Head>
        <title>Rental Agreement</title>
    </Head>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Does this answer your question?: [Set margin/padding for each page to print?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55682653/14933870)