# Detect and act on "page break" condition in CSS?

Tags: html, css, page-layout

This is admittedly an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The X is [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document) in a way that works in Safari 11.1.1. However, ***this*** question is specifically about a problem I have with my Y approach described below!

For my document (a résumé), I have a small fixed number of possible "page break" positions, enforced via `page-break-inside: avoid`. So it occurs to me that if I could detect the *actual* page-break location programmatically, then I could use that to de-`display:none` a footer element that I had previously set up in that location.  That is, my document currently looks like this:

```
.nobreak {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.footer {
    display: none;
}

    <div class="nobreak">
    <h2>Professional Affiliations</h2>
    <ul id="affiliations"> ... </ul>
    </div>

<div class="footer">footer text</div>

    <div class="nobreak">
    <h2>Licensure</h2>
    <ul id="licensure"> ... </ul>
    </div>

<div class="footer">footer text</div>

    <div class="nobreak">
    <h2>Publications</h2>
    <ul id="publications"> ... </ul>
    </div>

<div class="footer">footer text</div>
```

Is there any semi-reliable way to detect whether one of these "footer" elements is at the bottom of a (`media print`) physical page, and adjust its `display` property based on that?

I strongly suspect that this is impossible — because the newly revealed footer element would cause the page to reflow and move the footer element, and so on in an infinite regress — but I haven't seen it discussed anywhere so I thought I should ask for a definitive answer.

Comment: So basically you want a footer for every page printed?

Comment: @Pilan: Yes, "header and/or footer on every print page" is the X problem; but solutions to the X problem should be posted as answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document . *This* question is looking for answers specifically about how to unhide an existing element iff it's detected to be at the top and/or bottom of a print page.

Comment: Ok i see, this is the odd Y :D

Comment: I was recently trying to do something similar and wasn't able to find a way to definitively do it. I did however seem to have some success if I assumed the page was going to be x pixels high, based on the expected (or enforced) print aspect ratio. This worked in my case, but certainly had the potential to break given other machines printing.