# printing header on each page - code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print a header on each printed page, 
I have tried the code standalone and it works fine,
but when thrown in below context it only prints on the first page only
[sample report showing header on first page only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b2Go.jpg).

what am i doing wrong?

```
    //css style sheet

        <style> 
            @media screen {
                .only_print{
                    display:none;
                }

            }
            @media print {
                .no-print {
                    display: none !important;
                }

            }

        </style>

        <cfoutput>

        <p id="arr1" ></p>
        //below script generates the table wth header tag into <p> arr1


        <script type="text/javascript">
         function disptbl()
            { 
            var str1=localStorage.getItem('schedule');
        var p=localStorage.getItem('payno');
            var str='';
            var result = str1.split(',');

            //create table using thead and tbody

             str += ' <table width="92%" align="center">';
             str += '<thead>';
             str += '<tr class="only_print">';
             str += '<td colspan="3" align="center"> <h2><b>Data For #url.txtl#</b></h2></td>';
             str += '</tr>';
             str += '</thead>';
             str += '<tbody>';
```

for loop to split data into columns

```
            for( var x=0; x < p; x++ ){ 
                str += '<tr>';
                str += '<td align="right">'+result[6+x*10]+'</td>';
                str += '<td align="right">'+result[0+x*10]+'</td>';
            str += '</tr>';
            } 

            //assign create table to <p>

           document.getElementById("arr1").innerHTML = str; 
             }
```

call function

```
             disptbl();   
        </script>

        </cfoutput>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document)

Comment: From the linked duplicate, especially this seems to apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197225/1220550, quote: `The correct answer is that HTML 5 and CSS3 have no support for printing page header and footers in print media. And while you might be able to simulate it with (1) tables, (2) fixed position blocks - they each have bugs that prevent them from being the ideal general solution.`