# Printing and Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, flowdocument

I have a `Blazor` app that connects to an existing backend.  The Blazor app needs to print data from a `List<T>`.  What is the **correct** way of doing this?

In the WPF world, I would use a `DocumentPaginator`, however, since a `DocumentPaginator` `GetPage` method returns a `DocumentPage` which is a WPF `Visual` element this is out.

I have some luck creating a `FlowDocument` Something like this:

```
var doc = new FlowDocument();
var table1 = new Table();
doc.Blocks.Add(table1);
for (int x = 0; x < numberOfFields; x++)
{
    table1.Columns.Add(new TableColumn());
}
table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
int i = 0;
foreach (var x in MyList)
{
    table1.RowGroups[0].Rows.Add(new TableRow());   
    TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[0].Rows[i];
    AddFields(currentRow, i, x);
    i++;
}
```

That prints out a document however, I need page headers and footers.  Placing headers, footers, and page breaks can be done with `Paragraph` and `Section` are simple enough.  The problem is calculating when to apply the page break.  Everything I have seen to find out the height of something in FlowDocument uses a `FrameworkElement` to find it.

Very new to web, so if there is some simple solution I am sorry for asking.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Blazor question?

Comment: Maybe look to create a pdf. I did a little tutorial on that : https://github.com/tossnet/Blazor-PDF

Comment: Using the FlowDocument model is only making extra work. You can make up a page with HTML and blazor, a much richer toolkit. In the end you wil have to accomplish the paging with CSS anyway. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1360869/60761) and [this](https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/the-ultimate-print-html-template-with-header-footer-568f415f6d2a) and goole for much more.

Answer (score 5):

In combination with TossNet to generate the .pdf file you can use `Append.Blazor.Printing` to show the print dialog.

The repository can be found here: https://github.com/Append-IT/Blazor.Printing

[image]