# Is there a way to place a break to half a page when printing websites?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a website containing a form where I need to show it twice in one page when printing. I need to find a way to place the duplicate in the lower half of the page. The closest thing I saw was a page break but it goes to the next page instead of the lower half. Is there anyway to do that but for the lower half of the page instead?

Comment: Do you want to create a footer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document

Comment: Not really, I want the top half and the bottom half of the page to be the same size

Comment: Create a copy of your form in HTML. WIth CSS set the display to none for the second form. There is a print media query, using the print media query set the display to block for the second form. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media