# How to get <thead> and <tfoot> to not overlap cells when using <td rowspan>

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, html-table

So I'm making a `localhost` site to keep track of my families medications (upwards of 50 of them). I'm working on a page of it to `@print` out tables for each of us (4 total individuals) for when we fill our med containers each Sunday. All that said, my wife asked me to get the `<th>` to show on each page (top and bottom).

I did some research and found a great answer to the basic problem: [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document)

This is a great answer and I started there with the below table that is `echo`'d with `PHP`. I took out the `PHP` for now, but can add it if someone really needs it.. I use the `PHP` because the data is coming out of a `SQL`>`Database`>`Table`.

HTML (from PHP echo)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan='15' class='patientHeader'>[Family Member Name]'s Meds</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Drug Names</th>
            <th>Prescriber</th>
            <th>Dose/Pill</th>
            <th>Frequency</th>
            <th>Rx Number</th>
            <th>Time</td>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>M</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>W</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>F</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
            <th class='nf'>Next Fill</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<!-- BODY CONTENT -->
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Drug Names</th>
            <th>Prescriber</th>
            <th>Dose/Pill</th>
            <th>Frequency</th>
            <th>Rx Number</th>
            <th>Time</td>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>M</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>W</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>F</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
            <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
            <th class='nf'>Next Fill</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS

```
@media print {

    .menubar,
    h1.viewable,
    #pagewrapper,
    #footer,
    .subbar,
    #screenblock {
        display: none !important;
    }

    body {
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        font: 8pt Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 1cm;
        size: landscape;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 24pt;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 14pt;
        margin-top: 25px;
    }

    aside h2 {
        font-size: 18pt;
    }

    .body {
        display: block;
        width: 8.5in;
        height: 11in;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*************************VIEW TABLE STUFF*************************/
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border: 1px sold black;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        box-decoration-break: clone;
        -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
        page-break-after: always;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    th {
        font-weight: bold;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align:center !important;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
    }

    .smallBean {
        font-size: smaller;
        font-style: italic;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .tinyBoxes {
        width: 0.5cm;
        height: 0.5cm;
        font-weight: bold;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: .1cm;
    }

    .nf {
        width: 100px !important;
    }

    .nf::after {
        font-size: smaller;
        font-style: italic;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        content: "\A or \A Refil Needed";
        white-space: pre;
    }

    .onePage {
        page-break-before: always !important;
        page-break-after: always !important;
        page-break-inside: avoid !important;
    }
    .patientHeader {
        font-size: 0.4in;
        font-variant: small-caps;
    }
}
```

Here's the problem I run in to...

Within the gathering of the data and filling of the table, I use `<td rowspan=''>` and break down each medicine by when they are taken. **When** the table breaks on a row with this, the remaining `<td rowspan='1'>` get overlapped by the `<thead>`.

[IMGUR Image of what the print looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xexI.jpg)

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFORMATION **

> I did chose the `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` option from that link I posted because I want them attached to the *content* and not the *page*.

> > To clarify a comment

```
$am = $row['am'];
$noon = $row['noon'];
$pm = $row['pm'];
$bed = $row['bed'];
$prn = $row['prn'];
$other = $row['other'];

if ($other != 1) {
    if ($am == 1) {
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>AM</td>";
        $am = 0;
    } elseif ($noon == 1) {
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Noon</td>";
        $noon = 0;
    } elseif ($pm == 1) {
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PM</td>";
        $pm = 0;
    } elseif ($bed == 1) {
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Bed</td>";
        $bed = 0;
    } elseif ($prn == 1) {
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PRN</td>";
        $prn = 0;
    }
}

echo "<td tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>
        <td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>";
echo "<td rowspan='" . $rows . "' style='width:125px !important'>" . $nextFill . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

if (($rows > 1) && ($other != 1)) {
    if ($noon == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Noon</td>";
        echo "<td tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>
            <td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($pm == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PM</td>";
        echo "<td tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>
            <td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($bed == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Bed</td>";
        echo "<td tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>
            <td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($prn == 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PRN</td>";
        echo "<td tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>
            <td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td><td class='tonyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

> > The issue falls during these `<td rowspan = '1'>` tags

Comment: Not sure if this would do it, but you have a closing `</td>` on a `<th>`: `<th>Time</td>`

Comment: added more to the question - the issue is in `<td rowspan='1'></td>` and does not involve `<th>` tags

Comment: Does this happen in both Chrome and Firefox? I think they differ nontrivially when printing tables.

Comment: I went back in and tested it, and yes. It's not so much the `@print` that is the problem, it was the `<td>` in the middle of the row that had their own row.

Comment: @aynber I fixed that when I tedted dgrogan's question - didn't help either - good catch though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some work and I figured out a bit of a workaround - not a great one, but it does achieve the purpose I was going for...

> 1. I removed the `<tfoot>` - it wasn't necessary and was where the problem was being caused.
> 2. I found an error in my `<td class='tinyBoxes'> cells - some said "tonyBoxes" and a few were missing the` class='` portion

```
echo "<td class='tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>
<td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>";
echo "<td rowspan='" . $rows . "' style='width:125px !important;font-size:0.15in;'>" . $nextFill . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

if (($rows > 1) && ($other != 1)) {
    if ($noon == 1) {
        echo "<tr class='tiny'>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Noon</td>";
        echo "<td class='tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>
<td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($pm == 1) {
        echo "<tr class='tiny'>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PM</td>";
        echo "<td class='tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>
<td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($bed == 1) {
        echo "<tr class='tiny'>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>Bed</td>";
        echo "<td class='tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>
<td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    if ($prn == 1) {
        echo "<tr class='tiny'>";
        echo "<td rowspan = '1'>PRN</td>";
        echo "<td class='tinyBoxes'></div><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>
<td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td><td class='tinyBoxes'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

AND

```
/*
echo "
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Drug Names</th>
        <th>Prescriber</th>
        <th>Dose/Pill</th>
        <th>Frequency</th>
        <th>Rx Number</th>
        <th>Time</td>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>M</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>W</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>T</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>F</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
        <th class='tinyBoxes'>S</th>
        <th class='nf'>Next Fill</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>";
*/
```