# I need a simple footer that does not overlay the content on each page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I searched long for a solution to my problem.

I have a simple 1 div report that spans more than 1 page and I need to add a custom footer div that is 8cm in height

so on printing my page is size A4 Portrait
margins are:
top: 3cm (empty space)
left & right 1cm
bottom needs to be 8cm and within it I need to display my custom footer

I tried everything and still no result

2 simple divs

```
<div class="main-content">
main content goes here
</div>

<div class="custom-footer">
footer goes here
</div>
```

any idea how to do this guys ?

here is a full code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My HTML Page</title>
    <style>
    @media print {
      @page {
        margin-bottom: 8cm;
      }
    }
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 50px; /* set the height of the footer */
            
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #333;
            border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    
        
    </style>
    
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Repeat the <p> element 50 times to make the printout more than 1 page -->
    <?php
    for ($i=0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        echo "<p>Content goes here</p>";
    }
    ?>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <p>This is the footer of the page</p>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

I followed the advice from the comments below and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My HTML Page</title>
  <style>
    @media print {
      @page {
        size: A4;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-left: 1cm;
        margin-right: 1cm;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }

      .header-space {
        height: 3cm;
      }

      .footer-space {
        height: 8cm;
      }

      .footer {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 8cm;
        bottom: 0;
        border-top: 2px solid black;
      }
    }
  </style>



</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="header-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.

            Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.

            Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.

            Pellentesque vitae augue sed purus dictum ultricies at eu neque. Nullam ut mauris a purus tristique euismod. Sed elementum, leo id placerat congue, leo tellus pharetra orci, eget ultricies odio quam sit amet ipsum. Praesent feugiat, lorem at commodo egestas, felis ligula pharetra sapien, in placerat mauris nisi aliquet tortor. Quisque nibh lectus, laoreet vel mollis a, tincidunt vel ipsum. Sed blandit vehicula sollicitudin. Donec et sapien justo. Ut fermentum ipsum imperdiet diam condimentum, eget varius sapien dictum. Sed sed elit egestas libero maximus finibus eu eget massa.

            Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.

            Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero. Vestibulum bibendum molestie dui nec tincidunt. Mauris tempus, orci ut congue vulputate, erat orci aliquam orci, sed eleifend orci dui sed tellus. Pellentesque pellentesque massa vulputate urna pretium, consectetur pulvinar orci pulvinar.

            Donec aliquet imperdiet ex, et tincidunt risus convallis eget. Etiam eu fermentum lectus, molestie eleifend nisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam dignissim, erat vitae congue molestie, ante urna sagittis est, et sagittis lacus risus vitae est. Sed elementum ipsum et pellentesque dignissim. Sed vehicula feugiat pretium. Donec ex lacus, dictum faucibus lectus sit amet, tempus hendrerit ante. Ut sollicitudin sodales metus, at placerat risus viverra ut.

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vestibulum metus sit amet urna lobortis sollicitudin. Nulla mattis purus porta lorem tempor, a cursus tellus facilisis. Aliquam pretium nibh vitae elit placerat vestibulum. Duis felis ipsum, consectetur id pellentesque in, porta sit amet sapien. Ut tristique enim sem, laoreet bibendum nisl fermentum vitae. Ut aliquet sem ac lorem malesuada sodales. Fusce iaculis ipsum ex, in mollis dolor dapibus sit amet. In convallis felis in orci fermentum gravida a vel orci. Sed tincidunt porta nibh sit amet varius. Donec et odio eget odio tempus auctor ac eget ex.

            Duis finibus vestibulum finibus. Nunc lobortis lacus ut libero mattis tempor. Nulla a nunc at nisl elementum congue. Nunc eu consectetur mauris. Etiam non placerat massa. Etiam eu urna in metus tempus molestie sed eget diam. Nunc sem velit, elementum sit amet fringilla in, dictum sit amet sem. Quisque convallis faucibus purus dignissim dictum. Sed semper, mi vel accumsan sollicitudin, massa massa pellentesque justo, eget auctor sapien enim ac elit.

            Nullam turpis augue, lacinia ut libero ac, rhoncus bibendum ligula. Mauris ullamcorper maximus turpis, a consequat turpis bibendum sit amet. Nam vitae dui nec velit hendrerit faucibus. Vivamus nunc diam, porta tristique augue nec, dignissim venenatis felis. Proin mattis id risus in feugiat. Etiam cursus faucibus nisi. In in nisi ullamcorper, convallis lectus et, ornare nulla. Cras tristique nulla eros, non maximus odio imperdiet eu. Nullam egestas dignissim est, et fringilla odio pretium eleifend. Nullam tincidunt sapien fermentum, rhoncus risus ac, ullamcorper libero.</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>


  <div class="footer">
    this is my footer
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

still the same result, here is the print preview:
[image]

Comment: What is the current result you are getting from this? What is specifically not working? Is it overlapping the rest of the content, the measures are wrong? Are you printing at the original size?

Comment: every time the footer is overlaying the content

imagine if I have a word document I want the footer of each page to display the 8cm height custom footer I have

Comment: This seems to be very tricky. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document. Some examples may or may not work. **See especially this answer and also read its comments**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197225/20896315

Comment: Guys CSS is starting to play tricks on me
If I put the footer height to 256px it works like magic
anything above 256px and it ignores it and reverts back to 0
Why ???