# How to Create PDF with recurring logo using iText, HTML and thymeleaf

Tags: html, pdf, itext, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I am making use of HTML, thymeleaf and flying-saucer-pdf

I have the code at following link to convert html to pdf: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/html-pdf-generation-1x

HTML: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/html-pdf-generation-1x/blob/main/src/main/resources/pdf-templates/order-template.html

Java To Convert HTML to PDF using iText: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/html-pdf-generation-1x/blob/main/src/main/java/in/connect2tech/html/pdf/HtmlToPdfMain.java

Everything works fine and below is the sample PDF generated.

[image]

---

**Problem Statement**: The problem arises when the record spans more than 1 page. I am not able to create the header in all the pages, as can be seen in the screenshot below, the records start without the header and logo.

**Question**:How can I repeat the header logo on all the generated pdfs.

Thanks for any pointers/help in advance.

---

[image]

Comment: This is a common problem when converting HTML, which is continues, to discontinuous PDF pages. If you're lucky the software that creates the PDF acts as if it is printing the HTML, and in that case you could use [@page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) together with some [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) queries to repeatedly show the header in the PDF only. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS 2.0 paged media to define a header on your HTML document.

- Create a div which contains the content to be repeated as header

```html
<div id="header">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img width="80" src="https://simplesolution.dev/images/Logo_S_v1.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <h1>Supply Order Form</h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td th:text="'Date: ' + ${#dates.format(order.date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"></td>
            </tr>
           (...)
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Add the following CSS to repeat this content on each page

```css
@page {
    @top-center {  content: element(header);  }
    margin-top:10cm; /* Adjust this value to the size of the element */
                     /* you want to repeat on each page              */
}
#header {
    position: running(header);
}
```

You will also probably want to repeat the header of the table.

For that, you need to put the first line in a `<thead>` and the content in a `<tbody>`.

```html
<table class="order">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item #</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        (...)
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And then add the following CSS on the table

```css
.order {
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```