# How not to allow the main content to overlap the header and footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have this html file, that I'm using to generate a pdf with a header and footer on every page, but after the first header, the main content overlaps with the footer and the header. How do i solve this?

```
<html>
        <head>
          <style>
            @page {
              size: A4;
            }
            body {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
            }
            /* Apply the header to every page */
            #header {
              font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              color: #111111;
              font-size: 16px;
              text-align: left;
              position: relative;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              height: 40mm; /* Adjust the height of the header */
              break-after: always;
            }
            /* Apply the footer to every page */
            #footer {
              font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
              color: #111111;
              font-size: 16px;
              text-align: left;
              position: fixed;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              height: 40mm; /* Adjust the height of the footer */
              break-after: always;
              background-color: white;
            }
            /* Create a wrapper for the main content to offset for header and footer */
            #main-content-wrapper {
              flex: 1;
              padding-bottom: 40mm; /* Add the height of the footer */
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
          </style>
          
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="header">${headerWithData}</div>
          <div id="main-content-wrapper">
             <div id="main-content">${template}</div>
          </div>
          <div id="footer">${footerWithData}</div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

I tried adding page breaks to the footer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      @page {
        size: A4;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      /* Apply the header to every page */

      #header {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #111111;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        height: 40mm;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        /* Adjust the height of the header */
        break-after: always;

        background: red;
      }
      /* Apply the footer to every page */

      #footer {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #111111;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: left;
        height: 40mm;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        /* Adjust the height of the footer */
        break-after: always;
        background-color: white;

        background: blue;
      }
      /* Create a wrapper for the main content to offset for header and footer */

      #main-content-wrapper {
        padding-top: 40mm;
        padding-bottom: 40mm;
        /* Add the height of the footer */
        box-sizing: border-box;

        background: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">${headerWithData}</div>
    <div id="main-content-wrapper">
      <div id="main-content">
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template template template template template template template template template template
        template template template
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">${footerWithData}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try above code, seems to works for me.

The key is to make both header and footer position: fixed, see [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document) for details.

[image: print results screenshot]

Comment: doesnt the main content get cut off? but its almost done

Comment: ah, right, I guess your best bet it to just hide header/footer when printing, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7197225/4536543

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the margin on the

```
@page {
   size: A4;
   margin: 60pt 0;
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but doesn't seem to help..