# XHTML thead, tfoot and tbody importance

Tags: xhtml

Does XHTML have an 'opinion' regarding the use of `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>`?

Is there a case where they should be used?

Thank you.

Comment: Whenever you have a `<table>` you are **always** using at least a `<tbody>`. A `<tbody>` element is required in every table, but the opening and closing tags are optional (they can be inferred from the presence of a `<tr>`). This will be apparent if you ask a `<tr>` for its `.parentNode` or a `<table>` for its `.childNodes` even when you left the `<tbody></tbody>` out of the document.

Comment: @Gareth - not in true XHTML. i.e. When served as application/xhtml+xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The thead, tbody, and tfoot elements
>   in HTML are used to group table rows
>   into logical sections based on their
>   content. There are two main reasons
>   you'd want to do this:
>
> - To allow the body to be scrolled    independently of the header and/or
>     footer
> - To make it easier to apply different    style rules to the
>     different sections    of the table.

as stated here [What is benefit of <thead>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700379/what-is-benefit-of-thead/2700400#2700400)

If you are using tables to make layout then don't use these. If you are showing tabular data then use it.

And if you don't have anything to put in `tfoot` then don't add this.

You will find some good answers here also [What is benefit of <thead>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700379/what-is-benefit-of-thead)

Comment: Thank you m-s-g. So, if I write `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`, the `<tbody>` will not get added automatically by the browser? IE for example does this when you inspect a table with the Developer Tool.

Comment: @Francisc: No, an implicit `<tbody>` always gets added.

Answer (score 8):

They allow you to add semantics to your table, and also allow you to style the head and the foot of the table without introducing redundant classes/ids.

I can't think of a situation where you *have* to use it, although I know some jQuery plugins use the head & foot to control behaviors.

If your tabular data needs headings and summary rows, use them, if not don't

Answer (score 5):

The only rules, that I'm aware of, is that the `thead` (if used) must be defined *first*, and the [`tfoot`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TFOOT) (if used) *before* the `tbody` (somewhat counter-intuitive, to my mind, but them's the rules).

I think that the purpose of `thead` is partially for print purposes, allowing columns printed on a second page to have the `thead` repeated, in order that the data makes more sense.

In theory it could also allow for a scrolling `tbody` in the case of long tables, with fixed headers:

> This division enables user agents to support scrolling of table bodies independently of the table head and foot. When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data.
>
> Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TFOOT

This does not, however, work currently (without using at least two tables, I think).

The largest benefit, though, as [@Glenn Slaven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817547/are-there-cases-where-thead-tfoot-tbody-should-be-used-in-an-xhtml-document/3817604#3817604) notes, seems to be semantic.

Comment: The idea of putting `<tfoot>` before `<tbody>` is so that summary (footer) information can be rendered while a large data table is still downloading

Comment: @Gareth, yeah. It makes *sense* to do it that way, but it just feels, as I say, counter-intuitive is all. =)

Comment: Note that it's valid to put the `tfoot` either before or after the `tbody` s in (X)HTML5. Gareth's reasoning is sound, but like David, most people found the HTML4 way of doing it counter-intuitive, so the rules were relaxed. It makes no difference to the way browsers work, it's just a validity change.