# How do I make table headers repeat when printed?

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, css-tables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/css-repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)

I can repeat the headers in Firefox but not IE or Chrome. I am using the thead and tbody tags (which work in Firefox) Also I have added

```
<thead style="display:table-header-group;">
```

but it still wont work in Chrome. However, it now works in IE.

Comment: I recommend to add some code examples, because in this rate this question is already closed -- as it is too vague.

Comment: @CPX I have tried that... but it still wont work in Chrome.

Comment: @AllisonC, please read the [faq]. If a dup exists, the onus is on you to apply a bounty to the question that you feel needs a better answer.

Comment: I think also need to use th elements inside the thead.

Comment: @Gerben - I'm doing that