# Printing long tables with pretty page breaking behavior? possible?

Tags: javascript, printing, tabular

Can you use Javascript to do the following pseudocode? (in a browser)
explanation of below code:
similar to word processor behavior, it will take a long table that overflows a page break and split the cells so that there is no graphical breakage, and repeat the header row on the next page if the table has a header row (or multiple header rows).

Example of problem:

[image]

```
if printing page to pdf
{
 if table is overflowing a page break
 {
  if table has header row
   {
   split table so that rows print without breaking and repeat header row on next page
   }
  else if table does not have header row
   {
   split table so that rows print without breaking
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: In a browser? (I ask because of the "if printing to pdf" bit; Adobe uses JavaScript embedded in PDFs for various things.)

Comment: You shouldn't be using Javascript to generate the PDF as it can't. Also  you need to take into account the text sizes, what font is being used etc. There are plenty of server-side routines that will generate a pdf file from a server-side generated table or html.

Comment: @jeff: *"You shouldn't be using Javascript to generate the PDF as it can't."* Sure it can: http://parall.ax/products/jspdf ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - didn't now about that - thanks for the info.

Comment: CSS's page-break-before comes to mind. you could combine with nth-child to paginate the rows into pages

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JavaScript to do it: Instead, use [`thead`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-thead-element) elements to contain your table headers, and [`tbody`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tbody-element) elements to contain your table data. It's the browser's responsibility to repeat the table headers after page breaks.

Comment: that's awesome if it works, but does the browser actually do this? any examples? everywhere i've printed from in firefox/chrome/ie, the table rows break

Comment: @Gallaxhar: Firefox does, IE9+ does, shockingly it doesn't look like Chrome does (grrr), not even with [this hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/css-repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode). My test page: http://jsbin.com/dekehe/1 In my view, that's the user's/browser vendor's problem, not yours. :-) There's an [open Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826), and  a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205).

Comment: try it with a graphical border on the tables, and you will see it doesnt work in FF or IE either, unless it happens by chance luck

Comment: @Gallaxhar: Yeah, browsers are pretty awkward about what aspects of visual elements they do and don't print (backgrounds, some borders, etc.).