# Print CSS header at each page in a multi page document

Tags: print-css

Want to add a header on each page in the Printed document.

Used `page-break-inside: avoid`, as if some portion of the content is going to next page, it should completely go to next page.

The problem occurs when the content itself takes more than a page.
The table structure is

```
<table class="super-table">
    <thead class="pageheader">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $header; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $content[0]; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $content[1]; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $footer; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
    thead { 
        display: table-header-group; position: running(pageheader);
    }
    tr, td {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    @page {
        size: letter portrait;
        @top-left { content: element(pageheader); }
    }
    .super-table {
        page-break-after: always;
    }
}
```

The header overlaps when the content takes up more than a page. Can I have a margin set for content only in each page and not the header? Adding margin-top to `@page` shifts down the header also.

[IMAGE: `<thead>` overlaps if content occupies more than one page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4zij.png)

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with PHP but with CSS. PHP cannot manipulate with website design, it just outputs content.

You are probably looking for this: [Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the new [page module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) of css.

But as this is not supported by browsers until now, you can have a look at [paged.js](https://pagedjs.org/).