# Split table on Chrome when printing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, tabular

I want to split a table between groups in our organisation. This is (without the red lines) what I have on this moment:

[image]

I have a header that is on every page (the gray bar) what is great, but it is not on the right page, this is the first page and it is at the bottom again and not on the top of the second page. How can I fix this?

Also I want a "new page" on the red lines, so the table is split between the factions of or group. I have tried many css codes but none did something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode

Comment: @Stephan-v, sorry but i have a header but it's on the wrong page