# Print repeatable multiple header in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

So my problem has already been said in the title, I am trying to print a very long table with my header repeated on each page. The behaviour is there when I have 1 header with 1 row. But, what I'm currently having is either 1 of these 2 cases:

- Multiple headers (multiple thead)
- 1 header but with multiple rows

Both of the case seems to result in the header not being repeatable. Can anyone show me any workaround this?

-- EDIT 2 --

Some test cases:

- Firefox 57: Sometimes work, sometimes doesn't with 2 rows at most
- Chrome 62: Works with 2 rows header/ 2 headers, not working with 3

-- EDIT 1 --

My HTML code is quite simple and nothing much

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I'm currently using bootstrap css so it has already set style @print for my thead.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `print`?  Can you show the relevant part of your code?

Comment: @PM77-1 `print` as printing the whole page. I have edited to add my code but it's not really something big

Comment: Printing by what means? Just a `print` function of your browser?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes. Just normal printing

Comment: Explore `@media print` or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode

Comment: @PM77-1 that's already been set through bootstrap, so no extra code need to be set

Comment: Your example does not show you using Bootstrap.

Comment: @PM77-1 I did say below my code that I'm using bootstrap css

Comment: @PM77-1 is pointing out that your example does NOT have bootstrap. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to give good reproduction examples.

Comment: Also mention which browsers you have tried that exhibit the problem.

Comment: @dgrogan since bootstrap `@media print` set the style to thead, and tbody directly without adding extra class, I don't feel the need of adding anything inside my code?

Comment: @dgrogan I have added some browser that I have tried