# Node.JS HTML to PDF

Tags: node.js, node-html-pdf

I want to convert the HTML to PDF for which I am using this package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).

But in this HTML I am also getting tables and that tables can come in any position in HTML.
So I want to copy the table thead to another page if the table in the HTML exceeds more than 1 page.

Can you please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you find any solutions by yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to modify the CSS of the page to properly handle a printable view.

See also:  [Repeat table headers in print mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode)

Comment: Hello Brad, I have already checked this, Node.Js is not accepting this.

Comment: @RaviBadoni Node.js doesn't have to "accept" anything... you need to inject the CSS into the page for PhantomJS to render it.  That's what your package is using.

Comment: I have injected the thead css in HTML and sent the request to node, still I am getting pdf but thead is not copied to another page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Puppeteer to create PDF from HTML

Example from here https://github.com/chuongtrh/html_to_pdf

Or https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer